# How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, parsing, user-defined-functions, alphanumeric, alphabetic

How could you remove all characters that are not alphabetic from a string?

What about non-alphanumeric?

Does this have to be a custom function or are there also more generalizable solutions?

Answer (score 433, accepted):

Try this function:

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Call it like this:

```
Select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters('abc1234def5678ghi90jkl')
```

Once you understand the code, you should see that it is relatively simple to change it to remove other characters, too.  You could even make this dynamic enough to pass in your search pattern.

Comment: This code removes non-alpha characters (so numbers are also removed).  If you want to leave the numbers (remove non-alpha numeric characters), then... 

replace ^a-z with ^a-z^0-9

That search string appears in the code in two different places.  Be sure to replace both of them.

Comment: From Jeff's comment: I think that if wanted to strip all non-letters and non-numbers, you would want '^a-z0-9' (versus '^a-z^0-9', which would leave ^ in the string).

Comment: +1 George.  This is one of those places where "Set-Based" code and the use of Inline Scalar Functions have great difficulty in beating Row-By-Row.  Nicely done.  I've also been using your "Initial Caps" function, which has the same basic form, for a couple of years, now.

Comment: How can we modify this one to preserve spaces in the string?

Comment: @a12jun You can modify it to change the KeepValues variable to include a space, like this: '%[^a-z ]%'

Comment: For Case sensitive implementations use [^a-Z]

Comment: How would I modify this so it removes the characters but doesn't remove spaces?

Comment: @Lynchie Change '%[^a-z]%' To '%[^a-z ]%'  Basically, just put a space character after the z.

Comment: For more information see [MSDN documentation on the PatIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

Comment: This is a brilliant and very efficient solution - thank you very much for the work. I do, however, find that it removes one of the A's if the temp expression has 'AA' in it. So effectively '10NCAA3!#' will be 'NCA' and not 'NCAA' as (at least I) expected?

Comment: @StigMeyerJensen, when I run the code as posted, it returns NCAA.  Did you modify the code at all?

Comment: @GMastros Using 100% the same function becuase I thought it was my midifications. I just copied the function and pasted Again to make sure it was 100% the same and
Select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters('10NCAA3!#')
Still returns 'NCA'
Maybe it's system related? I'm on MSSQL 11.0.3155

Comment: When I replace the special character with a space it keeps on executing how we can handle that.

Comment: Variable name KeepValues is actually opposite of what it is meant to do. KeepValues lists the characters that need to be excluded..

Comment: for (german) users who struggle with ß, read https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/922b7cdf-3a57-4a1a-b267-3c919eb6fe13/sql-server-2005-is-silently-being-converted-to-ss-in-the-where-clause?forum=sqlgetstarted

Answer (score 217):

Parameterized version of [George Mastros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408129/george-mastros)' [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/1008566#1008566):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StripCharacters]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MatchExpression =  '%['+@MatchExpression+']%'
    
    WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
        SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')
    
    RETURN @String
    
END
```

Alphabetic only:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters('a1!s2@d3#f4$', '^a-z')
```

Numeric only:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters('a1!s2@d3#f4$', '^0-9')
```

Alphanumeric only:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters('a1!s2@d3#f4$', '^a-z0-9')
```

Non-alphanumeric:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters('a1!s2@d3#f4$', 'a-z0-9')
```

Comment: I prefer this version and created my adaptation of G Mastros' answer before scrolling down to vote it up!

Comment: The regex pattern doesn't seem to work with all whitespace.
If I want to strip all special characters except alphanumeric characters and whitespace I'd expect to use `SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters('a1!s2 spaces @d3# f4$', '^a-z0-9\s')` which still strips whitespace.  
I also tried to use `[[:blank:]]` but that breaks the function and nothing is removed from the string.
The closest Ive gotten is by using: `SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters('a1!s2 spaces @d3# f4$', '^a-z0-9 ')` (hard-coding a space in the regex pattern). However that doesn't remove line breaks.

Comment: @BillyMcKee  Add the space at the beginning instead of adding it at the end of the regular expression. `SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters('a1!s2 spaces @d3# f4$', '^ a-z0-9')`

Comment: @Miguel how do we preserver special characters such as (/!:\£&^?-:;|\)? ]%  ;:_|!" ?

Comment: @Even Mien how do we preserver special characters such as (/!:\£&^?-:;|)? ]% ;:_|!" ?

Comment: If I have string with 'é' in it.  It does not remove the é

Comment: @Graham My guess is that it has to do with supplementary character-aware (SCA) collations for your server, database, or column. Testing with this worked for me and my server collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS: select val, dbo.fn_StripCharacters(val, 'a-z') as stripped from (values ('e1'), ('E2'), ('é3')) as t(val)

Comment: +1 for the addition of extra domain vocabulary in this answer. It's always the same, one guy says "remove" or "clean" and it sticks to the code for eternity. But if that guy was in relation with its ecosystem instead of working alone, he would know it's a *Strip* or an *Escape* or a *Sanitize* ... domain is more important than code.

Answer (score 12):

Believe it or not, in my system this ugly function performs better than G Mastros elegant one.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveSpecialChar (@s VARCHAR(256)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(256) 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
    BEGIN
        IF @s IS NULL
            RETURN NULL
        DECLARE @s2 VARCHAR(256) = '',
                @l INT = LEN(@s),
                @p INT = 1

        WHILE @p <= @l
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @c INT
                SET @c = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@s, @p, 1))
                IF @c BETWEEN 48 AND 57
                   OR  @c BETWEEN 65 AND 90
                   OR  @c BETWEEN 97 AND 122
                    SET @s2 = @s2 + CHAR(@c)
                SET @p = @p + 1
            END

        IF LEN(@s2) = 0
            RETURN NULL

        RETURN @s2
```

Comment: what about common commas, periods, space, etc?

Comment: how much differ if you don't use `ASCII` integer here and compare directly the output of `SUBSTRING` with some chars, eg: `SET @ch=SUBSTRING(@s, @p, 1)` and `IF @ch BETWEEN '0' AND '9' OR @ch BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' OR @ch BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' ...`

Comment: Add WITH SCHEMABINDING to his function like your function has.

You're using VARCHAR, his function is using NVARCHAR.  If the parameters you are passing into his function are VARCHAR you should use VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR within his function otherwise, your system will need to cast the string values from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR before it can perform the function which is more expensive.

Even with those changes your function still might be faster, but those are a few examples I can see where his function might perform slower for you in your situation.

Comment: His function is also using NVARCHAR(MAX) and your function is using VARCHAR(256).  If 256 is all you need, change his function to use VARCHAR(256) too and his function will work faster for you.

Comment: This one removes the é character, so gets my vote

Answer (score 7):

I knew that SQL was bad at string manipulation, but I didn't think it would be this difficult. Here's a simple function to strip out all the numbers from a string. There would be better ways to do this, but this is a start.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AlphaOnly (
    @String varchar(100)
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS BEGIN
  RETURN (
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                      REPLACE(
                        @String,
                      '9', ''),
                    '8', ''),
                  '7', ''),
                '6', ''),
              '5', ''),
            '4', ''),
          '3', ''),
        '2', ''),
      '1', ''),
    '0', '')
  )
END
GO

-- ==================
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    ColID       int,
    ColString   varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, 'abc1234567890')

SELECT ColID, ColString, dbo.AlphaOnly(ColString)
FROM @t
```

**Output**

```
ColID ColString
----- ------------- ---
    1 abc1234567890 abc
```

**Round 2 - Data-Driven Blacklist**

```
-- ============================================
-- Create a table of blacklist characters
-- ============================================
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.CharacterBlacklist'))
  DROP TABLE dbo.CharacterBlacklist
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.CharacterBlacklist (
    CharID              int         IDENTITY,
    DisallowedCharacter nchar(1)    NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'0')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'1')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'2')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'3')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'4')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'5')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'6')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'7')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'8')
INSERT INTO dbo.CharacterBlacklist (DisallowedCharacter) VALUES (N'9')
GO

-- ====================================
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.StripBlacklistCharacters'))
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.StripBlacklistCharacters
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripBlacklistCharacters (
    @String nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @blacklistCt  int
  DECLARE @ct           int
  DECLARE @c            nchar(1)

  SELECT @blacklistCt = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.CharacterBlacklist

  SET @ct = 0
  WHILE @ct < @blacklistCt BEGIN
    SET @ct = @ct + 1

    SELECT @String = REPLACE(@String, DisallowedCharacter, N'')
    FROM dbo.CharacterBlacklist
    WHERE CharID = @ct
  END

  RETURN (@String)
END
GO

-- ====================================
DECLARE @s  nvarchar(24)
SET @s = N'abc1234def5678ghi90jkl'

SELECT
    @s                  AS OriginalString,
    dbo.StripBlacklistCharacters(@s)   AS ResultString
```

**Output**

```
OriginalString           ResultString
------------------------ ------------
abc1234def5678ghi90jkl   abcdefghijkl
```

**My challenge to readers: Can you make this more efficient? What about using recursion?**

Comment: you could probably write a better dbo.StripBlacklistCharacters() without a loop using  http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum table of numbers joined into your black list table, but I'm too lazy today to try it myself....

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that doesn't require creating a function or listing all instances of characters to replace. It uses a recursive WITH statement in combination with a PATINDEX to find unwanted chars. It will replace all unwanted chars in a column - up to 100 unique bad characters contained in any given string. (E.G. "ABC123DEF234" would contain 4 bad characters 1, 2, 3 and 4) The 100 limit is the maximum number of recursions allowed in a WITH statement, but this doesn't impose a limit on the number of rows to process, which is only limited by the memory available.
If you don't want DISTINCT results, you can remove the two options from the code.

```
-- Create some test data:
SELECT * INTO #testData 
FROM (VALUES ('ABC DEF,K.l(p)'),('123H,J,234'),('ABCD EFG')) as t(TXT)

-- Actual query:
-- Remove non-alpha chars: '%[^A-Z]%'
-- Remove non-alphanumeric chars: '%[^A-Z0-9]%'
DECLARE @BadCharacterPattern VARCHAR(250) = '%[^A-Z]%';

WITH recurMain as (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(TXT AS VARCHAR(250)) AS TXT, PATINDEX(@BadCharacterPattern, TXT) AS BadCharIndex
    FROM #testData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(TXT AS VARCHAR(250)) AS TXT, PATINDEX(@BadCharacterPattern, TXT) AS BadCharIndex
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN BadCharIndex > 0 
                THEN REPLACE(TXT, SUBSTRING(TXT, BadCharIndex, 1), '')
                ELSE TXT 
            END AS TXT
        FROM recurMain
        WHERE BadCharIndex > 0
    ) badCharFinder
)
SELECT DISTINCT TXT
FROM recurMain
WHERE BadCharIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

**Original answer**

Another possibe option for SQL Server 2017+, without loops and/or recursion, is a string-based approach using `TRANSLATE()` and `REPLACE()`.

T-SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @pattern varchar(52) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

SELECT 
   v.[Text], 
   REPLACE(
      TRANSLATE(
         v.[Text],
         REPLACE(TRANSLATE(v.[Text], @pattern, REPLICATE('a', LEN(@pattern))), 'a', ''),
         REPLICATE('0', LEN(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(v.[Text], @pattern, REPLICATE('a', LEN(@pattern))), 'a', '')))
      ),
      '0',
      ''
   ) AS AlphabeticCharacters
FROM (VALUES
   ('abc1234def5678ghi90jkl#@$&'),
   ('1234567890'),
   ('JAHDBESBN%*#*@*($E*sd55bn')
) v ([Text])
```

or as a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveNonAlphabeticCharacters (@Text varchar(1000)) 
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS BEGIN

   DECLARE @pattern varchar(52) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   SET @text = REPLACE(
      TRANSLATE(
         @Text,
         REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@Text, @pattern, REPLICATE('a', LEN(@pattern))), 'a', ''),
         REPLICATE('0', LEN(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@Text, @pattern, REPLICATE('a', LEN(@pattern))), 'a', '')))
      ),
      '0',
      ''
   )
   
   RETURN @Text
END
```

**Update**

Thanks to the @ttugates's comment, I've found a small issue in this approach. The actual edge case is the `'V 0 S'` as an input. The `LEN()` function truncates trailing spaces, which results in *"The second and third arguments of the TRANSLATE built-in function must contain an equal number of characters"* error message. A solution is a small change in the length calculation, but the approach remains the same:

- All alphabetic characters (or characters from the given pattern) in the input text are translated to `'a'` and after that replaced with `''`.
- The remaining text after the first step includes only non-alphabetic characters (or characters not in the given pattern).
- All non-alphabetic characters in the input text are translated to `'0'` and after that replaced with `''`.
- The remaining text is the actual result.
- The new length calculation is `LEN(REPLACE(@text, ' ', '.'))`.

Updated function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveNonAlphabeticCharacters (@Text varchar(1000)) 
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS BEGIN

   DECLARE @pattern varchar(52) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   DECLARE @translations varchar(1000)

   SET @translations = TRANSLATE(@Text, @pattern, REPLICATE('a', LEN(@pattern))) 
   SET @translations = REPLACE(@translations, 'a', '')

   SET @Text = TRANSLATE(@Text, @translations, REPLICATE('0', LEN(REPLACE(@translations, ' ', '.'))))
   SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text, '0', '')
   
   RETURN @Text

END
```

Comment: A space character IMO is an ASCII character and should be preserved

Comment: @Fandango68, in this case you  probably need a different pattren (`DECLARE @pattern varchar(53) = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`).

Answer (score 5):

Having looked at all the given solutions I thought that there has to be a pure SQL method that does not require a function or a CTE / XML query, and doesn't involve difficult to maintain nested REPLACE statements. Here is my solution:

```
SELECT 
  x
  ,CASE WHEN a NOT LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(x, 1, 1) + '%' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(x, 1, 1) END
    + CASE WHEN a NOT LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(x, 2, 1) + '%' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(x, 2, 1) END
    + CASE WHEN a NOT LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(x, 3, 1) + '%' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(x, 3, 1) END
    + CASE WHEN a NOT LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(x, 4, 1) + '%' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(x, 4, 1) END
    + CASE WHEN a NOT LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(x, 5, 1) + '%' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(x, 5, 1) END
    + CASE WHEN a NOT LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(x, 6, 1) + '%' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(x, 6, 1) END
-- Keep adding rows until you reach the column size 
    AS stripped_column
FROM (SELECT 
        column_to_strip AS x
        ,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' AS a 
      FROM my_table) a
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that the valid characters are contained in the one string in the sub query making easy to reconfigure for a different set of characters.

The downside is that you have to add a row of SQL for each character up to the size of your column. To make that task easier I just used the Powershell script below, this example if for a VARCHAR(64):

```
1..64 | % {
  "    + CASE WHEN a NOT LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(x, {0}, 1) + '%' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(x, {0}, 1) END" -f $_
} | clip.exe
```

Comment: Awkward in the general case, but easy and useful for a once-off query with a narrow column.

Answer (score 4):

If you are like me and don't have access to just add functions to your production data but still want to perform this kind of filtering, here's a pure SQL solution using a PIVOT table to put the filtered pieces back together again.

**N.B.** I hardcoded the table up to 40 characters, you'll have to add more if you have longer strings to filter.

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;

with 
    ToBeScrubbed
as (
    select 1 as id, '*SOME 222@ !@* #* BOGUS !@*&! DATA' as ColumnToScrub
),

Scrubbed as (
    select 
        P.Number as ValueOrder,
        isnull ( substring ( t.ColumnToScrub , number , 1 ) , '' ) as ScrubbedValue,
        t.id
    from
        ToBeScrubbed t
        left join master..spt_values P
            on P.number between 1 and len(t.ColumnToScrub)
            and type ='P'
    where
        PatIndex('%[^a-z]%', substring(t.ColumnToScrub,P.number,1) ) = 0
)

SELECT
    id, 
    [1]+ [2]+ [3]+ [4]+ [5]+ [6]+ [7]+ [8] +[9] +[10]
    +  [11]+ [12]+ [13]+ [14]+ [15]+ [16]+ [17]+ [18] +[19] +[20]
    +  [21]+ [22]+ [23]+ [24]+ [25]+ [26]+ [27]+ [28] +[29] +[30]
    +  [31]+ [32]+ [33]+ [34]+ [35]+ [36]+ [37]+ [38] +[39] +[40] as ScrubbedData
FROM (
    select 
        *
    from 
        Scrubbed
    ) 
    src
    PIVOT (
        MAX(ScrubbedValue) FOR ValueOrder IN (
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],
        [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20],
        [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30],
        [31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40]
        )
    ) pvt
```

Comment: This solution was 2.3x faster for me than using a function on a set of 235K rows. I also had to do 2x replacements, and used a total of four CTEs. Worked like a champ.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to remove non-alphabetic characters using an `iTVF`. First, you need a pattern-based string splitter. Here is one taken from Dwain Camp's [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/):

```
-- PatternSplitCM will split a string based on a pattern of the form 
-- supported by LIKE and PATINDEX 
-- 
-- Created by: Chris Morris 12-Oct-2012 
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PatternSplitCM]
(
       @List                VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
       ,@Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 

RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
        SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
            n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n)
    )

    SELECT
        ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
        [Matched]
    FROM (
        SELECT n, y.[Matched], Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.[Matched],n)
        FROM numbers
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT [Matched] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) y
    ) d
    GROUP BY [Matched], Grouper
```

Now that you have a pattern-based splitter, you need to split the strings that match the pattern:

```
[a-z]
```

and then concatenate them back to get the desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT Item + ''
    FROM dbo.PatternSplitCM(t.str, '[a-z]')
    WHERE Matched = 1
    ORDER BY ItemNumber
    FOR XML PATH('')
) x (a)
```

---

[**SAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10c31/1/0)

Result:

```
| Id |              str |              a |
|----|------------------|----------------|
|  1 |    test“te d'abc |     testtedabc |
|  2 |            anr¤a |           anra |
|  3 |  gs-re-C“te d'ab |     gsreCtedab |
|  4 |         M‚fe, DF |          MfeDF |
|  5 |           R™temd |          Rtemd |
|  6 |          ™jad”ji |          jadji |
|  7 |      Cje y ret¢n |       Cjeyretn |
|  8 |        J™kl™balu |        Jklbalu |
|  9 |       le“ne-iokd |       leneiokd |
| 10 |   liode-Pyr‚n‚ie |    liodePyrnie |
| 11 |         V„s G”ta |          VsGta |
| 12 |        Sƒo Paulo |        SoPaulo |
| 13 |  vAstra gAtaland | vAstragAtaland |
| 14 |  ¥uble / Bio-Bio |     ubleBioBio |
| 15 | U“pl™n/ds VAsb-y |    UplndsVAsby |
```

Comment: is there any advantage to use this over other answers?

Answer (score 2):

This solution, inspired by Mr. Allen's solution, requires a `Numbers` table of integers (which you should have on hand if you want to do serious query operations with good performance). It does not require a CTE. You can change the `NOT IN (...)` expression to exclude specific characters, or change it to an `IN (...)` OR `LIKE` expression to retain only certain characters.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT  SUBSTRING([YourString], N, 1)
    FROM    dbo.Numbers
    WHERE   N > 0 AND N <= CONVERT(INT, LEN([YourString]))
        AND SUBSTRING([YourString], N, 1) NOT IN ('(',')',',','.')
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS [YourStringTransformed]
FROM ...
```

Comment: Interesting solution to an unrelated issue.

Answer (score 2):

From performance perspective I'd use Inline Function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_RemoveNumericCharsFromString]
(
@List NVARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN

    WITH GetNums AS (
       SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
        n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
          (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
          (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
          (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
          (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n)
            )

    SELECT StrOut = ''+
        (SELECT Chr
         FROM GetNums
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(@List , n,1)) X(Chr)
         WHERE Chr LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
         ORDER BY N
         FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')


   /*How to Use
   SELECT StrOut FROM dbo.udf_RemoveNumericCharsFromString ('vv45--9gut')
   Result: vv--gut
   */
```

Comment: I know this thread is old but, an inline table valued function is the way to go. The problem with your solution is, because you're only returning numbers, this code: ),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  is not needed and will slow the function down by ~50%

Answer (score 2):

Here's another recursive CTE solution, based on @Gerhard Weiss's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917698/450750).  You should be able to copy and paste the whole code block into SSMS and play with it there.  The results include a few extra columns to help us understand what's going on.  It took me a while until I understood all that's going on with both PATINDEX (RegEx) and the recursive CTE.

```
DECLARE @DefineBadCharPattern varchar(30)
SET @DefineBadCharPattern = '%[^A-z]%'  --Means anything NOT between A and z characters (according to ascii char value) is "bad"
SET @DefineBadCharPattern = '%[^a-z0-9]%'  --Means anything NOT between a and z characters or numbers 0 through 9 (according to ascii char value) are "bad"
SET @DefineBadCharPattern = '%[^ -~]%'  --Means anything NOT between space and ~ characters (all non-printable characters) is "bad"
--Change @ReplaceBadCharWith to '' to strip "bad" characters from string
--Change to some character if you want to 'see' what's being replaced. NOTE: It must be allowed accoring to @DefineBadCharPattern above
DECLARE @ReplaceBadCharWith varchar(1) = '#'  --Change this to whatever you want to replace non-printable chars with 
IF patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, @ReplaceBadCharWith) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('@ReplaceBadCharWith value (%s) must be a character allowed by PATINDEX pattern of %s',16,1,@ReplaceBadCharWith, @DefineBadCharPattern)
        RETURN
    END
--A table of values to play with:
DECLARE @temp TABLE (OriginalString varchar(100))
INSERT @temp SELECT ' 1hello' + char(13) + char(10) + 'there' + char(30) + char(9) + char(13) + char(10)
INSERT @temp SELECT '2hello' + char(30) + 'there' + char(30)
INSERT @temp SELECT ' 3hello there'
INSERT @temp SELECT ' tab' + char(9) + ' character'
INSERT @temp SELECT 'good bye'

--Let the magic begin:
;WITH recurse AS (
    select
    OriginalString,
    OriginalString as CleanString,
    patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, OriginalString) as [Position],
    substring(OriginalString,patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, OriginalString),1) as [InvalidCharacter],
    ascii(substring(OriginalString,patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, OriginalString),1)) as [ASCIICode]
    from @temp
   UNION ALL
    select
    OriginalString,
    CONVERT(varchar(100),REPLACE(CleanString,InvalidCharacter,@ReplaceBadCharWith)),
    patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,CleanString) as [Position],
    substring(CleanString,patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,CleanString),1),
    ascii(substring(CleanString,patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,CleanString),1))
    from recurse
    where patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,CleanString) > 0
)
SELECT * FROM recurse
--optionally comment out this last WHERE clause to see more of what the recursion is doing:
WHERE patindex(@DefineBadCharPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,CleanString) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I put this in both places where PatIndex is called.

```
PatIndex('%[^A-Za-z0-9]%', @Temp)
```

for the custom function above RemoveNonAlphaCharacters and renamed it RemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters

Answer (score 1):

--First create one function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumericonly]
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @intAlpha INT
     SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
     WHILE @intAlpha > 0
   BEGIN
          SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
          SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
   END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

Now call this function like

```
select [dbo].[GetNumericonly]('Abhi12shek23jaiswal')
```

Its result like

```
1223
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server >= 2017...

```
declare @text varchar(max)

-- create some sample text
select
@text=
'
Lorem @ipsum  *&dolor-= sit?! amet, {consectetur } adipiscing\ elit. Vivamus commodo justo metus, sed facilisis ante 
congue eget. Proin ac bibendum sem/.
'

-- the characters to be removed
declare @unwanted varchar(max)='''.,!?/<>"[]{}|`~@#$%^&*()-+=/\:;'+char(13)+char(10)

-- interim replaced with
declare @replace_with char(1)=' '

-- call the translate function that will change unwanted characters to spaces
-- in this sample
declare @translated varchar(max)
select @translated=TRANSLATE(@text,@unwanted,REPLICATE(@replace_with,len(@unwanted)))

-- In this case, I want to preserve one space
select  string_agg(trim(value),' ')
from    STRING_SPLIT(@translated,' ')
where   trim(value)<>''

-- Result
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Vivamus commodo justo metus sed facilisis ante congue eget Proin ac bibendum sem'
```

Comment: Interesting solution, especially if you have a known list of unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE generated numbers table to examine each character, then FOR XML to concat to a string of kept values you can...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PatRemove](
    @pattern varchar(50),
    @expression varchar(8000) 
    )
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH 
        d(d) AS (SELECT d FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) digits(d)),
        nums(n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM d d1, d d2, d d3, d d4),
        chars(c) AS (SELECT SUBSTRING(@expression, n, 1) FROM nums WHERE n <= LEN(@expression))
    SELECT 
        @expression = (SELECT c AS [text()] FROM chars WHERE c NOT LIKE @pattern FOR XML PATH(''));

    RETURN @expression;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @vchVAlue NVARCHAR(255) = 'SWP, Lettering Position 1: 4 Ω, 2: 8 Ω, 3: 16 Ω, 4:  , 5:  , 6:  , Voltage Selector, Solder, 6, Step switch, : w/o fuseholder '


WHILE PATINDEX('%?%' , CAST(@vchVAlue AS VARCHAR(255))) > 0
  BEGIN
    SELECT @vchVAlue = STUFF(@vchVAlue,PATINDEX('%?%' , CAST(@vchVAlue AS VARCHAR(255))),1,' ')
  END 

SELECT @vchVAlue
```

Answer (score 0):

this way didn't work for me as i was trying to keep the Arabic letters i tried to replace the regular expression but also it didn't work. i wrote another method to work on ASCII level as it was my only choice and it worked.

```
 Create function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters] (@s varchar(4000)) returns varchar(4000)
   with schemabinding
begin
   if @s is null
      return null
   declare @s2 varchar(4000)
   set @s2 = ''
   declare @l int
   set @l = len(@s)
   declare @p int
   set @p = 1
   while @p <= @l begin
      declare @c int
      set @c = ascii(substring(@s, @p, 1))
      if @c between 48 and 57 or @c between 65 and 90 or @c between 97 and 122 or @c between 165 and 253 or @c between 32 and 33
         set @s2 = @s2 + char(@c)
      set @p = @p + 1
      end
   if len(@s2) = 0
      return null
   return @s2
   end
```

GO

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_spc_char(@str VARCHAR(MAX))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @resp    VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
  DECLARE @str_val   VARCHAR(MAX) = UPPER(@str);
  DECLARE @i       INTEGER= 1;
  DECLARE @v_asc   INTEGER;
   WHILE @i <= (LEN(@str_val))
   BEGIN
     SET @v_asc = (ASCII(SUBSTRING(@str_val, @i, 1))) 
        BEGIN
        IF @v_asc in (192,193,194,195,196,65) 
            begin
                SET @v_asc = 65;
                SET @resp = concat(@resp, CHAR(@v_asc));
            end;
        IF @v_asc in (200,201,202,203,233,69)
            begin
                SET @v_asc = 69;
                SET @resp = concat(@resp, CHAR(@v_asc));
            end;
        IF @v_asc in (204,205,206,207,296,73)
            begin
                SET @v_asc = 73;
                SET @resp = concat(@resp, CHAR(@v_asc));
            end;
        IF @v_asc in (210,211,212,213,214,79)
            begin
                SET @v_asc = 79;
                SET @resp = concat(@resp, CHAR(@v_asc));
            end;
        IF @v_asc in (217,218,219,220,85)
            begin
                SET @v_asc = 85;
                SET @resp = concat(@resp, CHAR(@v_asc));
            end;
        IF @v_asc in (199,231,67)
            begin
                SET @v_asc = 67;
                SET @resp = concat(@resp, CHAR(@v_asc));
            end;
        IF @v_asc in (209,78)
            begin
                SET @v_asc = 78;
                SET @resp = concat(@resp, CHAR(@v_asc));
            end;
        IF @v_asc in (924,181,358,216,222,330,272,208,198,42,37,38,34,36,35,
64,33,39,41,40,43,61,95,45,62,60,63,47,176,183,124,166,174,359,248,254,
180,170,186,126,312,331,273,172,178,179,163,162,123,91,93,125,92,167,240,
223,230,171,187,169,185,168)
            begin
                SET @resp = concat(@resp, '');
            end;
        ELSE 
            begin
                if @v_asc not in (65,67,69,73,78,79,85)
                begin
                    SET @resp = concat(@resp, CHAR(@v_asc));
                end;
            end;
        END;
      SET @i = @i + 1
    END;
    RETURN @resp;
END;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

Though post is a bit old, I would like to say the following.
Issue I had with above solution is that it does not filter out characters like ç, ë, ï, etc. I adapted a function as follows (I only used an 80 varchar string to save memory):

```
create FUNCTION dbo.udf_Cleanchars (@InputString varchar(80)) 
RETURNS varchar(80) 
AS 

BEGIN 
declare @return varchar(80) , @length int , @counter int , @cur_char char(1) 
SET @return = '' 
SET @length = 0 
SET @counter = 1 
SET @length = LEN(@InputString) 
IF @length > 0 
BEGIN WHILE @counter <= @length 

BEGIN SET @cur_char = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @counter, 1) IF ((ascii(@cur_char) in (32,44,46)) or (ascii(@cur_char) between 48 and 57) or (ascii(@cur_char) between 65 and 90) or (ascii(@cur_char) between 97 and 122))
BEGIN SET @return = @return + @cur_char END 
SET @counter = @counter + 1 
END END 

RETURN @return END
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Eric.  As you say, the post marked answer is very good, but it does not strip goofy "numeric" characters like ½.

Answer (score -3):

I just found this built into Oracle 10g if that is what you're using. I had to strip all the special characters out for a phone number compare.

```
regexp_replace(c.phone, '[^0-9]', '')
```

Comment: "SQL Server" refers specifically to Microsoft's product.