# Sql string manipulation within stored procedure

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

I have a field which contains article titles. I need to create friendly or pretty url's out of the article titles.

I need help manipulating the string with SQL. This has to be done within a stored procedure or function.

The requirements:
The only characters allowed are lowercase letters and numbers (a-z and 0-9)
All spaces need to be replaced with dashes.

Thanks!

(updated) I am using Sql Server 2008

Comment: What database & version?

Comment: I don't think that would be a good idea since you might end up with different items having the same URL. And to account for that in a stored procedure would significantly complicate the logic. Perhaps doing it outside your database would be a better option, whether you're going to do it often (e.g. on selection or insertion), or once off.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Sql Server 2008
@ShaderOp I already have the functionality in place to take care of duplicates. I was planning on doing all the manipulation before inserting the data but, it turns out most of the data is is already inserted in the database

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer over here. Thank you all!
[How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

CREATE Function [dbo].[create_pretty_url](@Temp VarChar(1000))

Returns VarChar(1000)

AS
Begin

```
While PatIndex('%[^A-za-z0-9]%', @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = LOWER(Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^A-za-z0-9]%', @Temp), 1, ''))

Return @Temp
```

End

Comment: Woops. spoke to soon. I need to replace spaces with dashes first...
any ideas?

Comment: Set @Temp = (Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^A-za-z0-9 ]%', @Temp), 1, ''))
Set @Temp = Replace(LOWER(@Temp),' ','-')

Answer (score 0):

To check for lowercase letters, you can use a binary collation like `Latin1_General_BIN`.

This SQL Server procedure checks if a string contains only spaces, digits or lowercase letters.  If so, it returns 1 and replaces spaces with underscores.  Else it returns -1.

```
if OBJECT_ID('TestProc') is null
    exec ('create procedure TestProc as select 1')
go
alter procedure TestProc(
    @str varchar(256),
    @result varchar(256) output)
as
begin
set @result = null
set @str = REPLACE(@str,' ','_')
if @str like '%[^0-9a-z_]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN
    return -1
set @result = @str
return 1
end
go
```

Test data:

```
declare @rc int
declare @result varchar(256)
exec @rc = TestProc '11 aa', @result out
select @rc, @result
exec @rc = TestProc 'NO CAPS', @result out
select @rc, @result
exec @rc = TestProc '%#$#$', @result out
select @rc, @result
```

-->

```
1           11_aa
-1          NULL
-1          NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not state which database, or version for that matter, but lets go with:

I you were to be using Sql Server 2005, 2008, have a look at using CLR functions

[Adding Regular Expressions (Regex) to SQL Server 2005](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-regular-expressions-regex-to-sql.html)