# Sort varchar column starting with the first letter instead of the first character?

Tags: sql, linq, sql-order-by

Using LINQ or SQL, how could I have the following strings, normally sorted as:

```
"banana"
apple
coconut
```

Sort as:

```
apple
"banana"
coconut
```

Comment: Well, you're asking SQL or LINQ to ignore the leading special character, so you'll need some form of regular expression, and you may end up loading the table into memory to clean up the data. It sounds risky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on your comment

```
IList<string> sorted = context.Terms.ToList()
    .OrderBy(t => Regex.Replace(t.Term, @"\W*","")).ToList();
```

Comment: I like your idea, but am unsure how to proceed. How would I apply your suggestion to the following: var query = from term in context.Terms orderby term.Term select term;

Answer (score 0):

On SQL you can sort it without needing `REGEX` functions per se, you can use `PATINDEX`. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY RIGHT(Column,LEN(Column)-patindex('%[a-zA-Z]%',Column)+1)
```

This way you are sorting the Table using the first letter of the column, ignoring the others characters

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I can only accept one answer, and I ended up using LINQ, but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column which contains just the alphanumeric string, then sort on this.

The function RemoveNonAlphaCharacters found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server/1008566#1008566) will allow you to filter out non alphanumeric characters.  If the table is very small and performance is not a problem, you could simply

```
ORDER BY RemoveNonAlphaCharacters(columnToClean)
```