# Remove special characters in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
      I have to remove the special characters from the selected string.
```

for example : I have string 'a&b' or 'a & b'. How can i remove special characters and concatenate these string into 'ab'.

Please can any one tell me.

```
SELECT @id= (UPPER(SUBSTRING(@a,1,2)))+(UPPER(SUBSTRING((SELECT table.column2 FROM tablename WHERE tablename.column1 = @b),1,2))) + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(@count as varchar(10)), 6)
```

Comment: **Just** `&` and whitespace or any non-alpha char?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

Comment: The UDF in the link does that very nicely.

Comment: thanks and sorry no more functions

Comment: You cant use a function?

Comment: how can i do that in stored procedure without using function

Answer (score 1):

The [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server) is by far the best option, if you must do it inline you can replace within a recursive CTE and use that as the base table;

```
select 1 as id,
       'qw2££!"£$%^&**(' as F into #TESTTABLE
insert #TESTTABLE 
values (2, 'xxx'),
       (3, ''), 
       (4,'$'),
       (5,'qq""ee$$')

;with cte(id, stripped) as (
    select id, cast(F as varchar(1024)) from #TESTTABLE
    union all 
    select id, cast(stuff(stripped, patindex('%[^a-z]%', stripped), 1, '') as varchar(1024))
    from cte
    where patindex('%[^a-z]%', stripped) > 0
)
select * from cte
    where patindex('%[^a-z]%', stripped) = 0
order by id
```

Result:

```
>>id  stripped
>>1   qw
>>2   xxx
>>3 
>>4 
>>5   qqee
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @temp varchar(30)
Set @temp = 'A & B'
While PatIndex('%[^a-z]%', @Temp) > 0
Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^a-z]%', @Temp), 1, '')

SELECT @id= (UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Temp,1,2)))+(UPPER(SUBSTRING((SELECT table.column2 FROM tablename WHERE tablename.column1 = @b),1,2))) + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(@count as varchar(10)), 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
  SET @str = 'a&b'
  WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
      SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')

  SELECT @str
```

For More Details [Click Here](http://dilipsinghdotnet.blogspot.in/2013/10/remove-special-characters-from-string.html)