# How to remove anything that is not a number from a raw string input in SQL Server 2005 or 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there an efficient way using sql server 2005 to remove all characters in a string like this which are not numbers?

```
TEXT T EXT TEXT 2345 TEXT SDTE
```

I was thinking there might be a way to combine the replace statement with a regular expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [answer from the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server/1008566#1008566), with the slight change needed to remove non-numbers as opposed to non-alphas:

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    While PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```