# Remove Alphabetic Characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to change

```
ABC2001  
ABCD2001 
ASDF111111
```

to

```
2001
2001
111111
```

I need to remove alphabetic characters in SQL Server, any idea?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this question...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server  You can use the function from the answer of that question to update your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below will take care

```
create function NoLetters(@string2number varchar(200)) 
 returns varchar(200)
as
begin
  declare @c int
  declare @num varchar(200)
  set @num = ''
  declare @txtCurrent char(1)
  set @c=1
  while @c<=len(@string2number)
    begin
     set @txtCurrent = substring(@string2number,@c,1)
     if ascii(@txtCurrent) between 48 and 57
       set @num = @num + @txtCurrent
     set @c=@c+1
   end
 return @num
end
```