# Extract Only charcters from a String

Tags: mysql

I have a column value like

```
lut00006300.txt  
sand2a0000300.raw
```

I need to extract only character data from above given column values. I tried the below query and was able to get the first three characters.

```
select filesize,
substring(Filename  FROM 1 FOR 3) AS Instrument from Collection;
```

Is there any approach to extract only the characters from the column value leaving the extensions

The results should be :

```
LUT  
SAND2A
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*only characters*"?  `l`, `u`, `t`, `0`, `6`, `3`, `.`, `x`, `s`, `a`, `n`, `d`, `2`, `r` and `w` are all characters!

Comment: I think *only alpha characters*.

Comment: @hims056: So the results should be `luttxt` and `sandaraw`?  Seems odd to me.

Comment: @eggyal oh yes. you are right.

Comment: No  I would like to retrieve only the character data before the extensions(.txt,.raw) Like LUT,SANDA2A

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will helps you.

```
select filesize,Filename from Collection where Filename REGEXP '[:alpha]';
```

Refer:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Thnks a lot but when i fire the above given query I got the output as 1

Comment: @user1633295 look this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
filesize,
UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Filename, '.', 1), '0', 1)) AS Instrument
FROM Collection;
```

This is a **dirty** solution, since you want to have the `2` in `SAND2A`.

Read more about the functions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html).