# Replace Ambigious / Invalid Text Characters from String

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008

I am inserting the string into table. But there are some ambiguous, illegal text characters like 'ÔÇô' , '├®' appearing in the string. I want to replace all these invalid characters from the table and update my table. Is there any way to replace such characters in SQL. I am using SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one of the functions here:

[How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

You haven't included your insert statement, so I'm going to guess you've done it similar to

```
insert into table2
SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters(myfield1, 'a-z0-9'), myfield2, myfield3 from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said... "Replace".

[Replace documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Hint: Replace the ambigous character with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can go for nvarchar, nchar or ntext to support these unicode chars in case you need those. If its really needs to replace the yous hould go for Replace() of Sql Server