# Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?

Tags: sql-server, regex

```sql
SELECT REPLACE('<strong>100</strong><b>.00 GB', '%^(^-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+$)%', '');
```

I want to replace any markup between two parts of the number with above regex, but it does not seem to work. I'm not sure if it is regex syntax that's wrong because I tried simpler one such as `'%[^0-9]%'` just to test but it didn't work either. Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Comment: You might want to revisit the answer.

Comment: What do you want the end result to be? Do you expect `100.00` or `100.00 GB`? And are there other examples of formatted numbers that do not fit the pattern of the markup only being around the part to the left of the decimal? Can markup be around the entire number such as `100<i>.00</i> GB`? Is there always a 2 character currency code on the right?

Comment: @srutzky I want number with decimal points if there are any, not all values have them, also there is virtually no pattern for these since it is generated but third party html generator. Sometimes currency is in front sometimes after number, sometimes it is symbol -$, sometimes code - USD, with -without spaces.. etc etc . simply very rubbish data

Comment: Anyone using SQL Server 2017 or newer I would suggest trying REPLACE and TRANSLATE for stripping out characters now.
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(ISNULL([textValue], ''), ' `~!@#$%^&*()=+_[]{}|\;:",<>.?/''', '--------------------------------'), '-', '')

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use [PATINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)
to find the first index of the pattern (string's) occurrence. Then use [STUFF](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to stuff another string into the pattern(string) matched.

Loop through each row. Replace each illegal characters with what you want. In your case replace non numeric with blank. The inner loop is if you have more than one illegal character in a current cell that of the loop.

```
DECLARE @counter int

SET @counter = 0

WHILE(@counter < (SELECT MAX(ID_COLUMN) FROM Table))
BEGIN  
   
    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @RetVal varchar(50)
        
        SET @RetVal =  (SELECT Column = STUFF(Column, PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Column),1, '')
        FROM Table
        WHERE ID_COLUMN = @counter)
        
        IF(@RetVal IS NOT NULL)       
          UPDATE Table SET
          Column = @RetVal
          WHERE ID_COLUMN = @counter
        ELSE
            break
    END
   
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Caution: This is slow though! Having a varchar column may impact. So using LTRIM RTRIM may help a bit. Regardless, it is slow.

Credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server) Stack Overflow answer.

Credit also goes to @srutzky

Instead of doing one row at a time, this answer can be adapted to a more set-based solution. It still iterates the max of the number of non-numeric characters in a single row, so it's not ideal, but I think it should be acceptable in most situations.

```
WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    WITH q AS
        (SELECT ID_Column, PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Column) AS n
        FROM Table)
    UPDATE Table
    SET Column = STUFF(Column, q.n, 1, '')
    FROM q
    WHERE Table.ID_Column = q.ID_Column AND q.n != 0;
    
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;
END;
```

You can also improve efficiency quite a lot if you maintain a bit column in the table that indicates whether the field has been scrubbed yet. (NULL represents "Unknown" in my example and should be the column default.)

```
DECLARE @done bit = 0;
WHILE @done = 0 BEGIN
    WITH q AS
        (SELECT ID_Column, PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Column) AS n
        FROM Table
        WHERE COALESCE(Scrubbed_Column, 0) = 0)
    UPDATE Table
    SET Column = STUFF(Column, q.n, 1, ''),
        Scrubbed_Column = 0
    FROM q
    WHERE Table.ID_Column = q.ID_Column AND q.n != 0;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 SET @done = 1;

    -- if Scrubbed_Column is still NULL, then the PATINDEX
    -- must have given 0
    UPDATE table
    SET Scrubbed_Column = CASE
        WHEN Scrubbed_Column IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE NULLIF(Scrubbed_Column, 0)
    END;
END;
```

If you don't want to change your schema, this is easy to adapt to store intermediate results in a table valued variable which gets applied to the actual table at the end.

Comment: In order for this solution to work, at the very least you need to add a period to the PATINDEX pattern; it should be: `[^0-9.]`. If not then you strip out the decimal and turn what should be `100.00` into `10000`.

Comment: @srutzky ok added '.'I was actually working on non-alphabet and thought doing ^0-9 would work.

Comment: +1 for effort, but (as you also pointed) this would make reports run way too long, they're slow as they are ... but for smaller data this is an excellent solution!

Comment: I just worked on something similar to this so I'm going to update the answer with a faster solution. It's still not ideal but performance should be acceptable in most situations.

Comment: @Tmdean: Thanks for contributing to this, I give it a try next time I come across similar problem.

Comment: You could wrap this in a function!

Answer (score 34):

Instead of stripping out the found character by its sole position, using `Replace(Column, BadFoundCharacter, '')` could be substantially faster. Additionally, instead of just replacing the one bad character found next in each column, this replaces all those found.

```
WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.YourTable
    SET Column = Replace(Column, Substring(Column, PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', Column), 1), '')
    WHERE Column LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%'
    If @@RowCount = 0 BREAK;
END;
```

I am convinced this will work better than the accepted answer, if only because it does fewer operations. There are other ways that might also be faster, but I don't have time to explore those right now.

Comment: Looks interesting, I don't have time to try it right now but will do when I have. Cheers

Comment: This helped me on a somewhat unrelated problem. I used your `Replace(Column, Substring(Column, PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', Column), 1), '')` bit on a select query. So, thanks!

Comment: @jyoseph Great! Just be aware that this will only remove all instances of a particular bad character, and has to be run repeatedly if the set of bad characters is greater than one...

Comment: @ErikE Thanks for the heads up! I used it to query a column which has phone numbers (modified the pattern slightly to %[^0-9]%) in order to strip out anything that is not numeric. So a user could query 333-1234 and it would match phone numbers inputted as 3331234. If I understand correctly, you're saying that in the case where the phone number is (333)-333-1234, it would only strip the first "("? I'll have to test that a bit more.

Comment: Correct. You could install a CLR module. Or ideally just do it in program code.

Comment: [ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN

Comment: @geoidesic There is no error in my SQL syntax, because this is Ms Sql Server, not MySQL. Of **course** you're going to get a syntax error running Sql Server SQL in MySQL.

Answer (score 24):

In a general sense, SQL Server does not support regular expressions and you cannot use them in the native T-SQL code.

You could write a CLR function to do that. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx), for example.

Comment: OK, that seems to be only way to go then... Thanks

Comment: Broken link. Which is why "See (link)" is something you're not supposed to do on Stackexchange.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for a performant and easy solution and are willing to enable CLR:

```sql
CREATE database TestSQLFunctions
go
use TestSQLFunctions
go
ALTER database TestSQLFunctions set trustworthy on

EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
go

CREATE ASSEMBLY [SQLFunctions]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 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
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE

go

CREATE FUNCTION RegexReplace(
    @input nvarchar(max),
    @pattern nvarchar(max),
    @replacement nvarchar(max)
) RETURNS nvarchar  (max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME SQLFunctions.[SQLFunctions.Regex].Replace; 

go

-- outputs This is a test 
SELECT dbo.RegexReplace('This is a test 12345','[0-9]','')
```

Content of the DLL:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function I wrote to accomplish this based off of the previous answers.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RepetitiveReplace
(
    @P_String VARCHAR(MAX),
    @P_Pattern VARCHAR(MAX),
    @P_ReplaceString VARCHAR(MAX),
    @P_ReplaceLength INT = 1
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Index INT;

    -- Get starting point of pattern
    SET @Index = PATINDEX(@P_Pattern, @P_String);

    while @Index > 0
    begin
        --replace matching charactger at index
        SET @P_String = STUFF(@P_String, PATINDEX(@P_Pattern, @P_String), @P_ReplaceLength, @P_ReplaceString);
        SET @Index = PATINDEX(@P_Pattern, @P_String);
    end

    RETURN @P_String;
END;
```

[Gist][1]
[1]: https://gist.github.com/jkdba/ca13fe8f2a9855c4bdbfd0a5d3dfcda2

### Edit:

Originally I had a recursive function here which does not play well with sql server as it has a 32 nesting level limit which would result in an error like the below any time you attempt to make 32+ replacements with the function. Instead of trying to make a server level change to allow more nesting (which could be dangerous like allow never ending loops) switching to a while loop makes a lot more sense.

*Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).*

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this post looking for something else but thought I'd mention a solution I use which is far more efficient - and really should be the default implementation of any function when used with a set based query - which is to use a cross applied table function.  Seems the topic is still active so hopefully this is useful to someone.

Example runtime on a few of the answers so far based on running recursive set based queries or scalar function, based on 1m rows test set removing the chars from a random newid, ranges from 34s to 2m05s for the WHILE loop examples and from 1m3s to {forever} for the function examples.

Using a table function with cross apply achieves the same goal in **10s**.  You may need to adjust it to suit your needs such as the max length it handles.

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveChars](@InputUnit VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    (
        WITH Numbers_prep(Number) AS
            (
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
            )
        ,Numbers(Number) AS
            (
                SELECT TOP (ISNULL(LEN(@InputUnit),0))
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                FROM Numbers_prep a
                    CROSS JOIN Numbers_prep b
            )
        SELECT
            OutputUnit
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    substring(@InputUnit,Number,1)
                FROM  Numbers
                WHERE substring(@InputUnit,Number,1) like '%[0-9]%'
                ORDER BY Number
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) Sub(OutputUnit)
    )
```

Usage:

```
UPDATE t
SET column = o.OutputUnit
FROM ##t t
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[RemoveChars](t.column) o
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the solution inside a SQL function could be useful if you want to reuse it.
I'm even doing it at the cell level, that's why I'm putting this as a different answer:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnReplaceInvalidChars] (@string VARCHAR(300))
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(300) = @string;
    DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR (20) = '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%';
    DECLARE @Len INT;
    SELECT @Len = LEN(@String); 
    WHILE @Len > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @Len = @Len - 1;
        IF (PATINDEX(@Pattern,@str) > 0)
            BEGIN
                SELECT @str = STUFF(@str, PATINDEX(@Pattern,@str),1,'');    
            END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            BREAK;
        END
    END     
    RETURN @str
END
```

A more speedy approach for large strings would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnReplaceInvalidChars] (@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = @string;
    DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR (MAX) = '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%';
    WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern,@str) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @str = STUFF(@str, PATINDEX(@Pattern,@str),1,''); 
    END     
    RETURN @str
END
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this solution is faster and simple. I use always CTE/recursive because `WHILE` is so slow on SQL Server.
I use it in projects I work with and large databases.

```sql
/*
Function:           dbo.kSql_ReplaceRegExp
Create Date:        20.02.2021
Author:             Karcan Ozbal

Description:        The given string value will be replaced according to the given regexp/pattern.

Parameter(s):       @Value       : Value/Text to REPLACE.
                    @RegExp      : The regexp/pattern to be used for REPLACE operation.

Usage:              select dbo.kSql_ReplaceRegExp('2T3EST5','%[0-9]%')
Output:             'TEST'
*/
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[kSql_ReplaceRegExp](
    @Value nvarchar(max),
    @RegExp nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max)

    ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT NUM = 1, VALUE = @Value, IDX = PATINDEX(@RegExp, @Value)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NUM + 1, VALUE = REPLACE(VALUE, SUBSTRING(VALUE,IDX,1),''), IDX = PATINDEX(@RegExp, REPLACE(VALUE, SUBSTRING(VALUE,IDX,1),'')) 
        FROM CTE
        WHERE IDX > 0
    )
    SELECT TOP(1) @Result = VALUE 
    FROM CTE 
    ORDER BY NUM DESC
    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: sorry, already has explain in code block description, parameters and usage.

Comment: Empirical testing of three methods listed in this and other responses are [1] CTE: 14s [2] patindex+STUFF: 79s [3] patindex+Replace: 4s.  It appears the patindex+replace method is the fastest given: MSSQL2019; 10,000 strings of 2048 characters in length.  I ask the author to elaborate on which use case the CTE method is best suited for.  Thank you.  I hope this helps other users make a decision since this thread is one of the top results for 'tsql regex replace' on google.

Answer (score 2):

I've created this function to clean up a string that contained non numeric characters in a time field. The time contained question marks when they did not added the minutes, something like this 20:??. Function loops through each character and replaces the ? with a 0 :

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CleanTime]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @intime nvarchar(10) 
)
RETURNS nvarchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ResultVar nvarchar(5)
    DECLARE @char char(1)
    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    DECLARE @i int = 1
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@intime)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @char =  CASE WHEN substring(@intime,@i,1) like '%[0-9:]%' THEN substring(@intime,@i,1) ELSE '0' END
    SELECT @ResultVar = concat(@ResultVar,@char)   
    set @i  = @i + 1       
    END;
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ResultVar

END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this just for a parameter coming into a Stored Procedure, you can use the following:

```
declare @badIndex int
set @badIndex = PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Param)
while @badIndex > 0
    set @Param = Replace(@Param, Substring(@Param, @badIndex, 1), '')
    set @badIndex = PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Param)
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `WHILE @Param LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was clearer:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func_ReplaceChars](
    @Value nvarchar(max),
    @Chars nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cLen int = len(@Chars);
    DECLARE @curChar int = 0;

    WHILE @curChar<@cLen
    BEGIN
        set @Value = replace(@Value,substring(@Chars,@curChar,1),'');

        set @curChar = @curChar + 1;
    END;

    RETURN @Value
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code similar to several codes above:

```
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCleanString]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCleanString] (@input VARCHAR(max), @Pattern 
VARCHAR (20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max) = @input;
    DECLARE @Len INT;
    DECLARE @INDEX INT;
    SELECT @Len = LEN(@input); 
    WHILE @Len > 0  
    BEGIN
        SET @INDEX = PATINDEX(@Pattern,@str);
        IF (@INDEX > 0)
            BEGIN
                SET @str=REPLACE(@str,SUBSTRING(@str,@INDEX, 1), '');               
            END         
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                BREAK;
            END
    END     
    RETURN @str
END
```

You can use it like this:

```
  SELECT CleanName = dbo.[fnCleanString](Name, '%[0-9]%') from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler and faster approach is iterate by each character of the alphabet:

```
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 0

WHILE(@i < 256)
BEGIN  

    IF char(@i) NOT IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.')      

      UPDATE Table SET Column = replace(Column, char(@i), '')

    SET @i = @i + 1

END
```

Comment: Please do not use something like this in production. You're making 245 updates without where clause. It works but it's far from an efficient approach. A better idea could be iterate through characters we want to remove instead all characters available on the alphabet. But even that could be improved to something better.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but I found the above solutions were a bit heavy. I found what I think is a slightly quicker and easier way to do it and it also provides flexibility on what to replace. I used '~' as a thow-away character but you could use any unused character to do the same job:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'S0m3 Rand0m t3xt w1th numb3rs 1n 1t'
declare @remove_chars varchar(100) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

print replace(Translate(@str, @remove_chars, replicate('~', len(@remove_chars))), '~', '')
```