# SQL Replace all characters in a string

Tags: sql, string, replace

Is there any SQL statements to replace everything in a string with an 'X'. The strings aren't all the same length so it makes it a bit tricky. I haven't been able to find anything that does this except the function below but it takes a long time when I pass in 'a-z0-9' since I have to search on all of those but I really just want to replace everything no matter what it is.

```
[dbo].[cfn_StripCharacters]
 (
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX), 
 @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)='a-z0-9'
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
SET @MatchExpression =  '%['+@MatchExpression+']%'

WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
    SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, 'X')

RETURN @String
```

For example the data column looks like this and I want to replace the whole string with x's:

975g  -> XXXX

ryth5  -> XXXXX

1234vvsdf5 -> XXXXXXXXXX

test1234 -> XXXXXXXX

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function)

Comment: If your goal is to obfuscate a field, why do you care the length of the string? Can you just `update tableName set protectedInfoColumn = 'XXX';`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is SQL Server, you can use the `REPLICATE` function and simply replicate `x` the `LEN()` of the string.

```
SELECT REPLICATE('x', LEN(@String))
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f084e/1)

*Edit - Looks like this is also available in MySQL via `REPEAT()` but I haven't tested*

Comment: This works perfectly. Have never heard of the Replicate function. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Tom - what is the way if I need to replace all characters except spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replicate and Len functions to replace all characters.

```
declare @str varchar(20)

set @str = 'abc'

select @str = REPLICATE('X', len(@str))

select @str
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to give the 'check' to the one who answered it first.

Answer (score -1):

There are no built in functions to do it.  You can write a CLR function that does a regex replace, though.