# Fetch string from dashed string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains dashed strings.

I want string between last dash and second last dash

Dash means `-`

SQL Server table

```
Create table tbl1 (vdocno varchar(200))

insert into tbl1 values('Abcd-67-Hji-kok-74-Kio')
insert into tbl1 values('Bki-6kdi7-jhfi-Hfjdji-koikk-7ji4-Kloio')
```

Desired output values:

```
74
7ji4
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5569)

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish this. You can use a string splitter, you can use reverse and substring. What have you tried?

Comment: since there don't seem to regexps in sql server, it might prove to be a challenge to write in plain sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Comment: @MarianP I am not the one who downvoted the question. I close-voted the question for being unclear.

Comment: Here's a [thread on splitting out a string][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x/25391776#25391776

Comment: Who deleted my initial comment!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the prettiest and I have no doubt it could be done more efficiently, but here's something that works that you could improve upon if required:

### [Demo SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5569/3)

```
create table tbl1 (vdocno varchar(200))

insert into tbl1 values('Abcd-67-Hji-kok-74-Kio')
insert into tbl1 values('Bki-6kdi7-jhfi-Hfjdji-koikk-7ji4-Kloio')

select vdocno,
reverse(substring(
    reverse(substring(vdocno, 1, LEN(vdocno) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(vdocno)))), 
         1, CHARINDEX('-',
                        reverse(substring(vdocno, 1, LEN(vdocno) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(vdocno))))
                     ) 
         - 1))
from tbl1
```

This reverses the string and strips off the section before and including the last dash, then using the reserved string, it removes the content after the first dash, before reversing it to be the right way round again.

Comment: oops missed the re-reverse