# Regular expression in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have the next issue, there is table with column data (type - nvarchar), this column can contains any characters, I need selected only data which are numbers or range of numbers, but to ignore white spaces. For example:

```
declare @tmp table (data nvarchar(192), Result nvarchar(192));

insert into @tmp SELECT '123', '<- valid';
insert into @tmp SELECT ' 123 ', '<- valid';
insert into @tmp SELECT '123-123', '<- valid';
insert into @tmp SELECT ' 123 - 123 ', '<- valid';
insert into @tmp SELECT '123jmj', '<- invalid';
insert into @tmp SELECT '123,5441', '<- invalid';
insert into @tmp SELECT '123,yjyj', '<- invalid';

SELECT * FROM @tmp
```

The result dataset must contains only valid rows. I can try the next

```
SELECT * FROM @tmp WHERE data NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

But I got only first row.

Comment: As the Regex-like functionality you can see is quite limited, how about some alternatives? Earlier versions (2005+) have the `ISNUMERIC() `function, and newer ones (2012+) you can use `TRY_PARSE()`.

Comment: You can `LTRIM(RTRIM(data))`, which will give your 2nd row as well. For the range you'll have to append an `OR` condition to your `WHERE`, it shouldn't be too difficult, but you may have to `REPLACE` the white spaces within the value.

Comment: @Bridge, `ISNUMERIC` is very unreliable, monetary signs and arithmetic signs also evaluate to true. `TRY_PARSE` won't work for the ranges.

Comment: @HoneyBadger is right - you need to handle the range of numbers yourself, I missed that requirement! Currently the Regex solution doesn't handle that either though :)

Comment: And none of the solutions currently proposed work for non-latin numeric characters either, I suspect.

Comment: @Bridge what are `non-latin numeric characters` ?

Comment: You can have a look at this [question] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - [here's a list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), what you consider numberic characters are not the same everywhere in the world. Not sure if I got the name right, I meant anything other than 0-9 - depends on OP's requirements really.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't support regular expressions at all - those are wildcards, not regexes. You could use SQL CLR to use .NETs `Regex` class if the performance is acceptable to you (it should be, since `like` like this wouldn't use indices anyway) and if you can enable SQL CLR in the first place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace the `white spaces` with `empty string`

Next replace the `-` with `.`

Third use [`ParseName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188006.aspx) trick to separate the data.

After the separation you can filter the records using `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

```
SELECT data
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Parsename(Replace(Replace(data, ' ', ''), '-', '.'), 2) st,
               Parsename(Replace(Replace(data, ' ', ''), '-', '.'), 1) ed
        FROM   @tmp) a
WHERE  st NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        OR ed NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: This works for the sample data, at least. Could you perhaps expand a bit how it works?

Comment: Parsename is only for sql +2012

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Please refer that link. It works from `2005`

Comment: @MM93 Your link say `Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2012 through current version),`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No, it's just the version for SQL Server 2014. You need to pick a different version of SQL server - this is the 2005 version https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188006(v=sql.90).aspx.

Comment: MM93, thank you very much, it's working on my SQL Server 2014. And thanks all for your time.