# How to replace &amp; to & in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, regex, sql-update

I have some bad data in my database table. I want to replace all `&amp;` or `&amp;amp;` or `&amp;amp;amp` or `&amp;amp;amp;amp` to `&` only.

In java it is working fine. how to do in SQL?

Java:

```
    String[] names = new String[] { "Ravi Suthar", 
                                    "Ravi &amp; Suthar", 
                                    "Ravi &amp;amp; Suthar",
                                    "Ravi &amp;amp;amp; Suthar",
                                    "Ravi &amp;amp;amp;amp; Suthar" };

    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name.replaceAll("&amp;[amp;]*", "&"));
    }
```

SQL:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname=REPLACE(columnname,'&amp;[amp;]*','&');
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Just fyi: This mostly happens when someone doesn't trust his xml parser and escapes the ampersand manually. Maybe you can fix this at the source!

Comment: Column data type is varchar and I am using ms sql server 2008.

Comment: Not possible in MSSQL as per this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Comment: @aksappy, yes it is. See my answer.

Comment: Your regex doesn't do what you intend. It matches `&amp;` followed by any number of the characters `a`, `m`, `p` and `;`. Try `(?:&(?:amp;)+)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname=REPLACE(REPLACE(columnname,'&amp;','&'), 'amp;', '');
```

This will first replace `"&amp;"` with `"&"`, then replace all `"amp;"` with `""` (empty string).

Answer (score 3):

Try to execute this one:

```
UPDATE Tablename
SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, '&amp;', '&')
WHERE columnname LIKE '%&amp;%'
```

Comment: It will replace &amp; to & which is ok, but &amp;&amp; to &amp; which is not ok.

Answer (score 1):

Following sql will replace `&amp;` or `&amp;amp;` or `&amp;amp;amp` or `&amp;amp;amp;amp` or its sequence to  `&`

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = REPLACE(REPLACE(columnname, '&amp;', '&'), 'amp;', '');
```

or

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname  = REPLACE(columnname , 'amp;', '')
```

Comment: Exactly what I said. You could accept my answer if it worked for you