# Extracting a variable length string between braces

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

This is the basic structure of some strings in a column:

```
CREATE TABLE #M(ST VARCHAR(250));
INSERT INTO #M
values
    ('please help me world  (produced... but needs to go)'),
    ('please help me world Y (produced_this is extra extra extra long)'),
    ('please help me world Z (producedthis isshort)'),
    ('please help me world K (produced');

SELECT * 
FROM   #M;
```

What I need to do is extract this `(produced%)' whenever it is found.

I can find occurrences of rows with the offending snippet `(produced%)' easily enough viathis:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    #M
WHERE   ST LIKE '%(PRODUCED%)%'
```

What I now need to do is delete the section from `(produced` up to the very next brace `)` - as you can see the distance between these two phrases is variable.

After querying I'd hope to have the following results:

```
'please help me world X'
'please help me world Y'
'please help me world Z'
'please help me world K (produced'
```

Because there is no closing brace in the 4th statement it is left as is.

---

EDIT

There could be text to the right of the offending phrase - so a better example of some strings is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #M(ST VARCHAR(250));
INSERT INTO #M
values
    ('please help me world  (produced... but needs to go) bb cc dd'),
    ('please help me world Y (produced_this is extra extra extra long)'),
    ('please help me world Z (producedthis isshort)'.xlsm),
    ('please help me world K (produced');
```

Comment: Is `(produced` always at the end of your string?

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23001916/2055998) is helpful.

Comment: @Lamak usually near the end but better if I write something that assumes that `(produced%)` could be anywhere in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify where `'(produced'` appears in your string using [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) then just extract the characters to the left (using [`LEFT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)). Finally you would need this inside a case expression to only apply the logic where there is a closing parenthesis:

```
SELECT  NewST = CASE WHEN ST LIKE '%(PRODUCED%)%' 
                        THEN LEFT(ST, CHARINDEX('(PRODUCED', ST) - 1)
                    ELSE ST 
                END
FROM    #M;
```

This gives:

```
NewST
------------------------------
please help me world  
please help me world Y 
please help me world Z 
please help me world K (produced
```

Which appears to be the desired output.

**EDIT**

I guess ')' isn't always going to be the last part of the string, in which case you need to identify this too, by using the optional third argument of `CHARINDEX` which is the starting position. The basics are:

```
SELECT  *,
        CloseParenthesis = CHARINDEX(')', ST, OpenParenthesis)
FROM    (   SELECT  ST,
                    OpenParenthesis = CHARINDEX('(PRODUCED', ST)
            FROM    #M
        ) AS t;
```

Which gives:

```
ST                                                                  OpenParenthesis     CloseParenthesis
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
please help me world  (produced... but needs to go)                 23                  51
please help me world Y (produced_this is extra extra extra long)    24                  64
please help me world Z (producedthis isshort)                       24                  45
please help me world K (produced                                    24                  0
```

Then you use these values for the position of the parenthesis inside the [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188043.aspx) function to remove everything between the parenthesis:

```
SELECT  ST,
        NewST = CASE WHEN ST NOT LIKE '%(PRODUCED%)%' THEN ST
                    ELSE STUFF(ST, OpenParenthesis, CloseParenthesis - OpenParenthesis, '')
                END
FROM    (   SELECT  ST,
                    OpenParenthesis = CHARINDEX('(PRODUCED', ST) - 1,
                    CloseParenthesis = CHARINDEX(')', ST, CHARINDEX('(PRODUCED', ST)) + 1
            FROM    #M
        ) AS t;
```

Comment: I'm saving my vote for when op answers the question I posted in a comment ;-)

Comment: @Lamak yes indeed ....apologies Gareth for the bad question....there could be text to the right of the phrase

Comment: One pitfall here is that if you have multiple occurrences of `(produced ....)` in the same string, only the first one would be removed, however, a solution for multiple replacements gets fairly complicated, so for now I will assume this is not going to be an issue.

Comment: @GarethD - only  ever one occurance - thanks for your time spent on this answer.