# SQL remove characters that aren't in a regex pattern

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

Suppose i have the following regex pattern of:

```
%[a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!-:,.']%
```

How could I iterate through a strings characters and remove (or replace with a blank) any characters that don't match the pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
PatIndex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!-:,.']%', YourValue)
```

will return the character at which the pattern matches. In this case, I've added `^` to the beginning so that the pattern matches everything *not* in the character set.

You can then remove the character at that position, and continue, or replace all occurrences of the found character in the entire string.

FYI: to simulate the `offset` parameter of `CharIndex` in order to search starting at a certain character position, you can use `Substring` to get a portion of the string (or even one character) and use `PatIndex` on that.

Comment: So using this I would have to wrap it in a while loop to factor in the scenario where more than one invalid character could be in the string correct?

Comment: Correct. There's no way to get some kind of map of the list of characters that don't match the pattern. You get to find out about one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Ok based on ErikE's help I made the following function

```
     CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveInvalidCharacters
 (
@pattern as varchar(max),
@string as varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    WHILE PatIndex(@pattern,@string) >0
      BEGIN
      SET @string=REPLACE(@string,SUBSTRING(@string,PatIndex(@pattern,@string),1),'')
END
RETURN @String

END
GO
```

Then all I do was call the function as:

```
  select dbo.RemoveInvalidCharacters('%[^a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.''-]%','Test€€€String^^^')
```

Then the output is:
TestString

Answer (score 0):

As [ErikE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57611/erike) mentions in his answer, the `PATINDEX` method is what you need, it is *SLOW* though.

An answer to a very similar question on SO is [stackoverflow.com/a/23001916/4316831](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23001916/4316831). The below code was taken from there:

```
DECLARE @counter int

SET @counter = 0

WHILE(@counter < (SELECT MAX(ID_COLUMN) FROM Table))
BEGIN  

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @RetVal varchar(50)

        SET @RetVal =  (SELECT Column = STUFF(Column, PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Column),1, '')
        FROM Table
        WHERE ID_COLUMN = @counter)

        IF(@RetVal IS NOT NULL)       
          UPDATE Table SET
          Column = @RetVal
          WHERE ID_COLUMN = @counter
        ELSE
            break
    END

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Comment: This is not much more than a link-only answer, which is frowned on. Could you expand on this a bit?

Comment: Good shout @ErikE, I wasn't sure of the etiquette of pasting someone else's code block, but I suppose if I credit it correctly it's okay.

Comment: Now that I think about it, perhaps it's better to flag this question as a duplicate of that one instead of just repeating the answer... ?

Comment: I don't have a high enough reputation to do that, hence the link to the answer.