# SQL find and replace text inside column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove all links from column_content in my table_name.
Links look like:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="/index.php?o=oda-res-site">.</a>
```

and  `href="........"` is different in each record.

Can you help with a statement with wildcards that will clean all links `<a ..../a>` ?

I tried this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'SearchForThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')
```

but I could not found the proper wildcards to include -if possible- all links.

Thank you
I use phpMyadmin

Comment: What database management program are you using?  add a tag for `sql-server`, `MySQL` or whatever it is.

Comment: What sort of information is in a `column_content` record?  Can there be multiple links?

Comment: `regexp_replace()` comes to mind

Comment: I use mysql and handle it with phpMyAdmin. Column type is:longtext so there can be other links that I do not want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

If it's SQL Server you're using, REPLACE doesn't handle wildcards or regex so you have to loop using PATINDEX instead.

[Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function)

Answer (score 0):

Hm... If I got you right, the solution shouldn't be that difficult. Following a sample code basing on your example:

```
DECLARE @MyString nvarchar(250) = N'<a style="text-decoration:none" href="/index.php?o=oda-res-site">.</a>';
SELECT @MyString as MyOldString, LEFT(@MyString, CHARINDEX('href="', @MyString)+5) + '">.</a>' as MyNewString
```

Comment: Thanks for your try but it didn't work. I have basic knowledge in mysql, so I just copy paste the above at phpMyAdmin > sql tab. The error is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Oh, ok, if it's mysql, the query might require some modification. I tested it on Sqlserver. Guess you might need to use instring or similar instead of charindex. Im not that familiar with mysql.