# Using Wildcards in SQL to delete part of a string

Tags: sql-server

I am cleaning up addresses so I can compare them between two databases. 
I want to delete the word "apt/unit" and the apartment number/letter that  follows.

```
Current                            Desired
20951 VIA OLEANDER APT E           20951 VIA OLEANDER 
7623 SOUTHAMPTON TER UNIT 209      7623 SOUTHAMPTON TER
```

Comment: Could you just test if the first address contains the second address? Similar to: first_address LIKE CONCAT(second_address, "%")

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Comment: Essentially, I want to delete everything after APT or UNIT