# Deleting everything after a certain word in a SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found statements that delete everything after a certain character. How do i delete everything after a word even though the length after that word may vary.

```
11000 PLACIDA RD BLDG 15 UNIT 1504
17200 ACAPULCO RD BLDG 1
```

I want to delete everything after BLDG

Comment: is your data will be like this for entire column

Comment: Not really, Im working with over 7 million unique addresses. I am trying to delete out buidling/unit/apartment numbers

Comment: Didn't you post a question that was almost exactly the same yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976762/using-wildcards-in-sql-to-delete-part-of-a-string

Comment: @JohnSpecko This is similar but different enough to class as a new question.

Comment: Yeah but I didnt receive as nearly as much feedback or help. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186323.aspx) to find the position of a string inside another string:

```
CHARINDEX('BLDG', ColumnName)
```

Then use [`LEFT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) to only take everything up to that point:

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('BLDG', ColumnName))
FROM Table
```

And finally, since you want to include the `BLDG` text, you need to add 3 to the position (i.e. length of the string-1):

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('BLDG', ColumnName)+3)
FROM Table
```

If you want to also delete the `BLDG` word, then subtract 1 instead:

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('BLDG', ColumnName)-1)
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
CREATE TABLE #DeleteString ( AddressB4 VARCHAR(255) );

INSERT  INTO #DeleteString
        ( AddressB4 )
VALUES  ( '11000 PLACIDA RD BLDG 15 UNIT 1504'  -- AddressB4 - varchar(255)
          ),
        ( '17200 ACAPULCO RD BLDG 1'  -- AddressB4 - varchar(255)
          );
DECLARE @SearchStrng VARCHAR(255)= 'BLDG';
SELECT  REPLACE(AddressB4,
                SUBSTRING(AddressB4,
                          CHARINDEX(@SearchStrng, AddressB4)
                          + LEN(@SearchStrng), LEN(AddressB4)), '') AS FilteredAddress
FROM    #DeleteString;
```

[image: Here are my results]