# Regex pattern inside REPLACE function

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

```
SELECT REPLACE('ABCTemplate1', 'Template\d+', '');
SELECT REPLACE('ABC_XYZTemplate21', 'Template\d+', '');
```

I am trying to remove the part `Template` followed by n digits from a string. The result should be

```
ABC
ABC_XYZ
```

However REPLACE is not able to read regex. I am using SQLSERVER 2008. Am I doing something wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function)

Comment: all that is after template too?

Comment: Yes @alex. Everything including the word `Template` and whatever succeeds after that(its only going to be digits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ABCTemplate1', 1, CHARINDEX('Template','ABCTemplate1')-1)
```

or

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ABC_XYZTemplate21',1,PATINDEX('%Template[0-9]%','ABC_XYZTemplate21')-1)
```

More generally,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,1,PATINDEX('%Template[0-9]%',column_name)-1)
FROM sometable
WHERE PATINDEX('%Template[0-9]%',column_name) > 0
```

You can use `substring` with `charindex` or `patindex` if the pattern being looked for is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTRING('ABCTemplate1',1, CHARINDEX ( 'Template' ,'ABCTemplate1')-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer expects that "Template" is enough to determine where to cut the string:

```
select LEFT('ABCTemplate1', CHARINDEX('Template', 'ABCTemplate1') - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numbers table..

```
;with cte
as
(select 'ABCTemplate1' as string--this can simulate your table column
)
select * from cte  c
cross apply
(
select replace('ABCTemplate1','template'+cast(n as varchar(2)),'') as rplcd
from
numbers
where n<=9
)
b
where c.string<>b.rplcd
```

Using Recursive CTE..

```
;with cte
as
(
select cast(replace('ABCTemplate21','template','') as varchar(100)) as string,0 as num
union all
select cast(replace(string,cast(num as varchar(2)),'') as varchar(100)),num+1
from cte
where num<=9
)
select top 1 string from cte
order by num desc
```