# SQL Server replace chars that are not in range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How i can replace all chars that are not in specified range of chars?

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @allowedChars VARCHAR(max)
SET @s = 'Foo@Bar !'
SET @allowedChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$_/+-.0123456789'

SELECT MAGICREPLACE(@s, @allowedChars,'_');
--Should return 'F___B____'
```

Comment: This operation is called `translate()` (after the Unix command, which has been around a long, long time).  There is not a simple way to do this in SQL Server, without writing your own function.

Comment: This might help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function . As Gordon said, there is no easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].MAGICREPLACE(@BUFFER VARCHAR(MAX), @PATTERN VARCHAR(128), @REPL VARCHAR(1)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @POS INT = PATINDEX(@PATTERN, @BUFFER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
    WHILE @POS > 0 BEGIN
        SET @BUFFER = STUFF(@BUFFER, @POS, 1, @REPL)
        SET @POS = PATINDEX(@PATTERN, @BUFFER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
    END
    RETURN @BUFFER
END
```

For

```
SELECT dbo.MAGICREPLACE('Foo@Bar !', '%[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9$_/+-.]%', '_')

> F___B____
```

Comment: Excellent! I din't know PATINDEX