# SQL convert any char to zero 0

Tags: sql, ssis, transform

So I'm exploring a table where I found a couple of fields that should be numerics, however as the source is an excel file so people have mixed already letters, symbols, and numbers.

I'm trying to clean up these fields but I can find too many kinds of symbols so currently, I've performed the cleaning with a couple of cases like:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN Montant_Devise LIKE '%Free%' THEN '0'
       WHEN Montant_Devise LIKE ' ' THEN '0'
       WHEN Montant_Devise = '' THEN '0' 
       WHEN Montant_Devise = '-' THEN '0' 
       ELSE CAST(COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Montant_Devise, '€', ''), ' ', ''), ',', '.'))), '0') AS DECIMAL(20,2))
    END
FROM
    [dbo].[table_BI]
```

So, the deal here is that probably I may find new symbols in the future than to avoid include the new symbols in my case I would like to know how could I replace doesn't matter which symbol or letter by the default 0 zero.

Do you know guys how I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just set this field to 0 by default? Can you provide more clarification on what you are trying to accomplish please, maybe some input and output examples.

Comment: check it out @JoshAdams by default the field already is mixed between numbers, letters and symbols

Comment: This is totally unclear. Please [edit] your post to be more specific about what you're trying to do and include your efforts to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: This will help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function.

Comment: check it out @KenWhite

Comment: Rather than trying to create a never-ending list of unacceptable values, would it not make more sense to define what you do want to accept (e.g. only the digits 0-9) and specifically check for and allow them?

Comment: I think looking and replacing is not the best solution. I would either: 1) update the database to use correct values, or 2) just hard ode an insert with '0' since it appears you will always set this to 0

Comment: We wary of your local specifier for thousands and decimal when applying some of the solutions this question may generate

Comment: sql server needs regex support

Comment: @OtoShavadze, this is SSIS so the OP could write a script task to use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this without a function, which is going to kill on performance. With that said, there are many out there. Here is one.

```
CREATE Function [fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '0')
    END
    RETURN @strText
END
```

The execution

```
declare @table table (x varchar(64) )
insert into @table
values
('332148790832473487...DFSKDJFH&#@!@#'),
('0X0C0V1234')

update t
set x = dbo.RemoveNonNumericCharacters(t.x)
from @table t

select * from @table
```

**RETURNS**

```
x
33214879083247348700000000000000000
0000001234
```

Alternatively, in the function you can just *remove* the non-numeric by changing

`STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '0')`

to...

`STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')`

Answer (score 2):

Start with

```
CASE WHEN patindex(Montant_Devise  '%[^0-9]%' > 0 '0'
```

Then do the empty string.  Then do your else.

Comment: buddy that will replace whole field as zero I just need clean up the field