# Any better way to remove junk characters than using too many Replace function?

Tags: string, t-sql, replace, sql-server-2012, character

I have something as under

```
declare @t table(city varchar(100))
insert into @t values('ab,c:d\/tyu'),('frd/hj&er\gg:')

select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(city,',',' '),'"',''),':',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\',''),'&','')
from @t

output
----------
ab cdtyu
frdhjergg
```

As can be figure out that, because of too many junk characters I am using many replace function.

Is there a better and elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Since I am using sql server 2014, i am left with replace and not Translate (sql server 2017)..pls.

Comment: There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I place this as a second answer as it is a completely new, set-based approach

As in my other answer I use a maintainable replace value's table:

```
CREATE TABLE ReplaceValues (FindChar VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
                           ,ReplWith VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
                           ,SortOrder INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO ReplaceValues VALUES(',',' ',1)
                               ,('"','',2)
                               ,(':','',3)
                               ,('-','',4)
                               ,('/','',5)
                               ,('\','',6)
                               ,('&','',7);
GO

declare @t table(city varchar(100))
insert into @t values('ab,c:d\/tyu'),('frd/hj&er\gg:');
```

--The query will use a *Tally* table to generate a running number on the fly. Then `SUBSTRING` is used to pick each and any single character and find it in the replace value's table. If nothing is found, the value is used, otherwise the replace value. Finally the separated characters are re-concatenated using `FOR XML`

```
WITH Tally AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nmbr FROM master..spt_values) --approx 2500 values. Need more? Use CROSS JOIN

SELECT t.city 
,(
    SELECT ISNULL(rv.ReplWith,SUBSTRING(t2.city,Nmbr,1))
    FROM @t AS t2
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (LEN(t2.City)) Nmbr FROM Tally) AS A
    LEFT JOIN ReplaceValues AS rv ON rv.FindChar=SUBSTRING(t2.city,Nmbr,1)
    WHERE t.city=t2.city
    ORDER BY A.Nmbr
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)') ReBuilt
FROM @t AS t
GO
--Clean-Up

DROP TABLE ReplaceValues;
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the rare situations where a *quirky update* is a good idea. Don't expect the best performance, but any other approach with loops, recursive CTEs etc will have their RBAR too...

The advantage of this approach is: You can maintain your replace values in a table. You can even replace longer strings with other longer strings and - which can be really magic: By defining the order, you can even do a cascading replace...

```
CREATE TABLE ReplaceValues (FindChar VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
                           ,ReplWith VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
                           ,SortOrder INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO ReplaceValues VALUES(',',' ',1)
                               ,('"','',2)
                               ,(':','',3)
                               ,('-','',4)
                               ,('/','',5)
                               ,('\','',6)
                               ,('&','',7);
GO
```

--Normally you cannot use the *quirky update* inlined, but you can wrap it within a scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MultiReplace(@ReplaceTarget VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    --Quirky Update: One of the rare situations where this is a good idea 
    SELECT @ReplaceTarget=REPLACE(@ReplaceTarget,rv.FindChar,rv.ReplWith)
    FROM ReplaceValues AS rv
    ORDER BY rv.SortOrder;

    RETURN @ReplaceTarget;
END
GO
```

--Your table

```
declare @t table(city varchar(100))
insert into @t values('ab,c:d\/tyu'),('frd/hj&er\gg:');
```

--...and the magic is going in here:

```
SELECT t.city
      ,dbo.MultiReplace(t.city) AS CleanedCity
FROM @t AS t
GO
```

--Clean-Up

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.MultiReplace;
DROP TABLE ReplaceValues;
```

The result

```
city            CleanedCity
ab,c:d\/tyu     ab cdtyu
frd/hj&er\gg:   frdhjergg
```

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar See my second answer... What is more important? Readability or principles? Btw: Quirky updates are quite good in performance...

Answer (score 1):

**Using Function**

**Try this:**

```
Create Function [dbo].[Removejunkcharacter]
 (@CityTempValue varchar(100))
 Returns varchar(100)
 AS
 Begin

    Declare @value as varchar(100)
    Set @value = '%[^a-z]%'
    While PatIndex(@value, @CityTempValue) > 0
        Set @CityTempValue = Stuff(@CityTempValue, PatIndex(@value, @CityTempValue), 1, '')

    Return @CityTempValue
End
```

**Execute Query:**

```
Declare @t table(city varchar(100))
Insert into @t values('ab,c:d\/tyu'),('frd/hj&er\gg:')

Select t1.city AS Input,
    [dbo].[Removejunkcharacter](t1.city) AS Result
    FROM @t AS t1;
```

**Result:**

```
   Input            Result

ab,c:d\/tyu        abcdtyu
frd/hj&er\gg:      frdhjergg
```

Comment: One problem with this approach (which is using the *quirky update* too), is the fact, that some values are not just to be removed... At least the comma is translated to a blank...

Comment: @Vinoth, I just want to avoid function...can this be done in a set based way?

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
declare @t table(id int, value varchar(15))

insert @t values(1, 'ab,c:d\/tyu')
insert @t values(2, 'frd/hj&er\gg')

;with t1 as
(
   select value i, id from @t
   union all
   select cast(replace(i, substring(i, PatIndex('%[^a-z0-9]%', i), 1), '') 
   as varchar(15)), id
   from t1
   where PatIndex('%[^a-z0-9]%', i) > 0
)

select t2.value as [Input], t1.i as [Result] from t1
join @t t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where PatIndex('%[^a-z0-9]%', i) = 0
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another fairly simple solution based on Shnugo's `ReplaceValues` table and a recursive cte:

Shnugo's table:

```
CREATE TABLE ReplaceValues (FindChar VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
                           ,ReplWith VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
                           ,SortOrder INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO ReplaceValues VALUES(',',' ',1)
                               ,('"','',2)
                               ,(':','',3)
                               ,('-','',4)
                               ,('/','',5)
                               ,('\','',6)
                               ,('&','',7);
GO
```

Sample data:

```
declare @t table(city varchar(100))
insert into @t values('ab,c:d\/tyu'),('frd/hj&er\gg:')
```

Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT city, 1 as level
    FROM @T 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(Replace(city,FindChar,ReplWith) as varchar(100)), level + 1
    FROM CTE 
    INNER JOIN ReplaceValues ON level = SortOrder
)

select TOP 1 WITH TIES City
from CTE
ORDER BY level DESC
```

Result:

```
City
1   frdhjergg
2   ab cdtyu
```