# Masking real values - I would like to mask alphanumeric values in a SQL server table to x

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, masking, alphanumeric

So here what I wanted:

Original value in a SQL server table with column comments:

```
Hyderabad 12-11-1989 " 123% "
```

Desired masked value

```
xxxxxxxxx xx-xx-xxxx " xxx% "
```

How can I get it in SQL server .. any function? Or update query ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function)

Comment: If you are trying to permanently replace them in the original table, see above.  If you are trying to mask the value returned, you'll want to create a view that uses the Regex replace in the example above as a calculated column and have queries point to the view rather than the original table.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server -2016

Comment: i tried below but I wanted to leave spaces and other punctuations to be as is ..ONLY change a-z,A-Z 0-9   SELECT REPLICATE('x', LEN(address)) from customers

select TRANSLATE(address, '[^a-z0-9]', 'x') from customers

Comment: SELECT REPLICATE('x', LEN(address)) from customers

select TRANSLATE(address, '[^a-z0-9]', 'x') from customers