# Regular expression for finding all occurrences of a pattern in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I need to replace Strings like  '1956678~26789~7230' and '1956678~26789' in 
https://baseurl/api/something/1956678~26789~7230/client/1956678~26789
with say like X. so it will be like 
https://baseurl/api/something/X/client/X. I was using the `replace` function, but I am not able to find the regex that I can use to replace the desired characters with X

So I want to use patindex to find position of following String in a given string. what is sql server regex version that can match all of the following strings:
1956678~26789~7230,
9889~454~234234~9089,
1~1~234.
 Eventually, I will use the substring and replace function to replace all of the above string with symbol X.

Comment: `b{2,}` will match `b` 2 or more times. See https://regex101.com/r/U6l7bl/1

Comment: its not working in sql though. I tried select REPLACE ('https://baseurl/api/something/bbbbb/client/bbbbbbbb','b{2,}','handle') api but same string I get back

Comment: SQL server does not easily support regex: [Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function). `REPLACE()` can only handle exact string replacements.

Comment: nope! here I have trouble finding regex that can be supplied to the second argument of replace.

Comment: That's too bad for you because `REPLACE()` does not support regex.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: this content maybe useful for solve your problem. you can use SqlRegex.dll for do this.https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/regex-in-sql-server-for-replacing-text

Comment: okay if i use patindex which take the regex, then what will be my regex for the above patter?I can use later substring with replace to do my task.