# Replace string using RegEx?

Tags: sql-server, regex

I need some help on how can I replace a string in SQL Server using RegEx.

Here is my sample:

```
SELECT REPLACE('@[Testing, Testing](c7f6eb1a-f365-4b27-8b11-0a69b1b2c827) test', '/(?:\]\()\w{0,8}\w(?:\-)\w{0,4}\w(?:\-)\w{0,4}\w(?:\-)\w{0,4}\w(?:\-)\w{0,12}\w(?:\))/g', '')
```

I want to remove this **](c7f6eb1a-f365-4b27-8b11-0a69b1b2c827)** using replace function of SQL Server.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 that replace is not to be used with regular expression.

> string_pattern
>
> Is the substring to be found. string_pattern can be of a character or binary data type. string_pattern cannot be an empty string (''), and must not exceed the maximum number of bytes that fits on a page.

Alternative solutions here: [Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function)

Comment: I already try it but it doesn't work. 

`DECLARE @RetVal varchar(50)

        SET @RetVal =  STUFF('@[Testing, Testing](c7f6eb1a-f365-4b27-8b11-0a69b1b2c827) test', PATINDEX('%[(?:\@\[)%', '@[Testing, Testing](c7f6eb1a-f365-4b27-8b11-0a69b1b2c827) test'),1, '') 

       PRINT @RetVal`

In my expression, I just want to remove only the **@** in my string but it doesn't work.

But anyway, Thank you so much for your response