# Cleansing data on SQL - String

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean my data on SQL. My sample data is below:

[image]

Could you please let me know how can I remove the date-time parts? Thanks,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvVxU0_a53vncGpd0Mbr57WPUbG89MgfpYGah0JBdIA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is the source of your data? Which language are you using? Are you inserting the cleaned data or selecting to display it? It may be easier to exclude unwanted data from the source.

Comment: I want to clean data on Microsoft SQL.

Comment: Is there even a thing called "Microsoft" SQL? I am afraid there is not.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvVxU0_a53vncGpd0Mbr57WPUbG89MgfpYGah0JBdIA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The document cannot be opened. Open the document on google drive the generate a shareable link then post it here.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvVxU0_a53vncGpd0Mbr57WPUbG89MgfpYGah0JBdIA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlbertAlberto Can please check the data?

Comment: Post any relevant information in the question itself. Explain what you want without forcing people to guess

Comment: I want to clean the data in SQL. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvVxU0_a53vncGpd0Mbr57WPUbG89MgfpYGah0JBdIA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want to remove the date string you'll have to do it with a language like C# or Python. SQL, the language, is very bad at text manipulation. It's a query language, not a general purpose language

Comment: Can I clean in python.

Comment: I want to remove the date from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is not particularly good at string manipulations.

However, based on the examples in your question, the "cleaning" is either removing the first 11 characters or the last 13 characters, depending on where the date is.  Fortunately, this is actually something you can do in SQL Server:

```
select t.*,
       (case when data like '% ([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])'
             then left(data, len(data) - 13)
             when data like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %'
             then stuff(data, 1, 11, '')
             else data
        end) as cleaned_data
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for selecting date-times that you want to remove:

```
(\(?[0-9]{2}\/){2}([0-9]{4}\)?)
```

Then replace that part of string with blank space, which is the same as removing.

To see how to use replace method in SQL with regex check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function).