# Comparing and replacing characters in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a string say 'Hel@1*oO'

```
Input string -- Hel@1*oO
```

I want to create a function that will parse through the string 'Hel@1*oO' and replace all characters other than alphanumeric with #.

Basically I want to use regex as [^A-Za-z0-9]. So that other than these characters everything will be replaced with #

```
The Output will be -- Hel#1#oO
```

We have REGEX_REPLACE() in Oracle that does the same functionality but I need to get this functionality in SQL Server.

What set of functions can be used to achieve this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function OR https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/regex-in-sql-server-for-replacing-text ?

Comment: Could you share what version of SQL Server you're using? (And that's `SELECT @@VERSION;`, not `Help > About` in Management Studio.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may have found out, T-SQL has no Regex support and thus no support for Regex replacement. You *can* achieve Regex support with CLR functions if needed, however, I'm not going to cover that here as there are a wealth of resources out there for that already if you want to go down that route.

Assuming, however, you are on a **fully** supported version of SQL Server, you can use a Tally to break the string into individual characters, and then reaggregate the string with `STRING_AGG` (if you aren't on a fully supported version, you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` method).

This gives you something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @String nvarchar(4000) = N'Hel@1*oO',
        @Pattern nvarchar(100) = N'[^A-Za-z0-9]',
        @ReplacementCharacter nvarchar(1) = '#';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@String))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN V.C LIKE @Pattern THEN @ReplacementCharacter ELSE V.C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I)
FROM Tally T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String,T.I,1)))V(C);
```

If you wanted to, you could convert this to an inline table-value function, and then use that against a column (or value):

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.PatternCharacterReplace (@String nvarchar(4000), @Pattern nvarchar(100), @ReplacementCharacter nvarchar(1)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP(LEN(@String))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)  --4096 rows; For a varchar(8000) or MAX you would need more rows for such lengths
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN V.C LIKE @Pattern THEN @ReplacementCharacter ELSE V.C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I) AS ReplacedString
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String,T.I,1)))V(C);
GO

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'Hel@1*oO'),('H0w 4re y0u? :)'))V(S)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.PatternCharacterReplace(V.S,N'[^A-Za-z0-9]',N'#') PCR;
```

Note that for the function, you may need to create multiple versions for `nvarchar` and `varchar` (and possibly explicitly ones for `MAX` length ones too)

Again, as mentioned, if you need true Regex replacement functionality, you'll need to look into CLR or do the operation *outside* of SQL Server.