# Keep only allowed characters in a string

Tags: sql, replace, sql-server-2016

If I know which characters I do not want to keep in my string I can easily remove them with `REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             'String with characters like #§$ I do not want to keep', 
             '#', ''
           ), '§', ''
         ), '$', ''
       ) AS repl_string

--- String with characters like  I do not want to keep
```

But, what if I want to remove every character which is not part of a positive list? With a `regex` I would so something like `s/[^a-zA-Z0-9 :.]//g` (assuming that I would like to allow only letters, numbers, a space  , a dot `.` or a colon `:`)

I am looking for a solution for Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Please add clarity with sample data and expected results. Sounds like a job for `translate` perhaps.

Comment: SQL Server does not support Regex, let alone Regex replacement. Though if you just want to keep the characters you list there, you could make use of SQL Server's basic pattern matching alongside the solution I have in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71662896/2029983)

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker  yes it is. Version 13 is SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Hm, when I click on properties in SSMS it shows exactly this: `Version: 13.0.6300.2`

Comment: Which is SQL Server 2016 SP2,  @thothal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses a very similar solution to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71662896/2029983) I linked above, however, as the OP is using SQL Server 2016, they can't use `STRING_AGG`. As such you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method to reaggregate the string:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PatternCharacterReplace_XML] (@String varchar(8000), @Pattern varchar(100), @ReplacementCharacter varchar(1)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP(LEN(@String))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
    SELECT (SELECT CASE WHEN V.C LIKE @Pattern THEN @ReplacementCharacter ELSE V.C END
            FROM Tally T
                 CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String,T.I,1)))V(C)
            ORDER BY T.I
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(8000)') AS ReplacedString;
GO


SELECT *
FROM dbo.PatternCharacterReplace_XML('String with characters like #§$ I do not want to keep','[^A-Za-z0-9 .:]','');
```

Note that this particular version uses `varchar` values. If your value is an `nvarchar` I would suggest creating a *separate* version that uses that data type for the parameters.