# Group by a column and ignore whitespace and special characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, removing-whitespace

I am trying to find records in my database (SQL Server) that have values in common. I am grouping them and counting them as below:

```
select count(ItemNum) as RecordCount, Vendor, PartNumber 
from Products
where (RecordCount > 2)
group by Vendor, PartNumber
order by RecordCount desc, Vendor, PartNumber
```

I want the result table to have all existing combinations of Vendor and PartNumber and look like `RecordCount, Vendor, PartNumber`

This works great, but sometimes there are minor differences in the values and I want to group them together despite those differences. Specifically I want to ignore whitespace and non-alphanumeric characters.

For example, PartNumber = "p120" should match with "p1_20" and "p1 20".

How can I do this?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @nbk Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: sql server is missng such functionality tried with a function like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Comment: If your part number is a string, how can you be sure `PL0-21` is the same as `PL02-1`? (I don't think you have a query problem to solve, I think you have a data problem to solve.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand The point of the query is to solve the data problem, by showing a user the potential duplicates and allowing them to resolve them. So, I have both problems :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use string functions to remove whitespaces. Here is list below:

[LTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) [RTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

These functions will remove / replace extra chars. For example:

```
-- PartNumber = " 120_1 "
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(PartNumber)), '_', '') FROM Products
-- PartNumber = "1201"
```

I created a table with test data:

```
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (25, 'VendorName', '1025');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (14, 'VendorName', '1_ 025');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (25, 'VendorName', '102 5');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (25, 'VendorName', '102_5');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (25, 'VendorName', ' 1025 ');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (25, 'VendorName', '102 5');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (223, 'OtherVendorName', '    9_02');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (102, 'OtherVendorName', '902');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (255, 'OtherVendorName', '  902 ');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (31, 'OtherVendorName', '902_');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (33, 'OtherVendorName', '9 02');
INSERT INTO Products (ItemNum, Vendor, PartNumber) VALUES (55, 'OtherVendorName', '  902  ');
```

Complete query with data from the previous code block.

```
SELECT COUNT(ItemNum) AS RecordCount, Vendor, REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(PartNumber)), '_', ''), ' ', '') AS PartNumber
FROM Products
GROUP BY Vendor, REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(PartNumber)), '_', ''), ' ', '')
HAVING COUNT(ItemNum) > 2
ORDER BY COUNT(ItemNum) DESC, 2, 3
```

Returns

| RecordCount | Vendor | PartNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | OtherVendorName | 902 |
| 6 | VendorName | 1025 |

Comment: Please don't use images for data, especially images which can't be seen without clicking a link. The editor allows tabular data as I have done for you.

Comment: Thank you for the note. I will do as you advised.

Comment: I suppose I can use replace for each unwanted character, but I imagine if will be slow.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are evaluating only numbers in those part numbers and letters are ignored...

```
SELECT COUNT(p2.PartNumber) RecordCount, p1.Vendor, p1.PartNumber 
FROM Products p1
LEFT JOIN Products p2 ON LEFT(SUBSTRING(p1.PartNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', p1.PartNumber), 4000),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(p1.PartNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', p1.PartNumber), 4000)))
= LEFT(SUBSTRING(p1.PartNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', p2.PartNumber), 4000),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(p2.PartNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', p2.PartNumber), 4000)))
GROUP BY p1.Vendor, p1.PartNumber,
HAVING COUNT(p2.PartNumber) > 2
ORDER BY COUNT(p2.PartNumber) DESC, Vendor, PartNumber
```

I just set the substring with a max for nvarchar since I don't know your data types.