# Search alphanumeric string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find the alphanumeric string of 9 character in sql server with or without special charatcer (other than alphanumeric charatcer like _ or /)
e.g. I have column name USER. In this column I have to select values having only alphanumeric characters like 123abc , 234def and not 23*kl or 25/bz.

Comment: Are you talking about random generated string?

Comment: pls add some more details..

Comment: No. I have to select the string from column having only 9 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: do you have a table which have alphanumeric string and you want that string to be searched ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
select * from [tbkname] where len([columnname]) = 9 AND columnname like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

Comment: Thanks Friayank! This is seems to be exact answer. But if I want the values having other characters than alphanumeric values........ not like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' will work or we have to add some more into it?

Comment: u mean to say special characters ?

Comment: Yes special characters like *, $,/ etc.

Comment: its simple just change the regular expression from alphanumeric to special character expression i.e '%[^.*?[!#$%&()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]+.*?$]%'

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like the following,

```
DECLARE @InputString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'D!E#$M&*O_@&1@&'
DECLARE @SrchExpr VARCHAR(255)
SET @SrchExpr =  '%[^a-z0-9]%'
    WHILE PatIndex(@SrchExpr, @InputString) > 0
        SET @InputString = Stuff(@InputString, PatIndex(@SrchExpr, @InputString), 1, '')
    SELECT @InputString
```

EDIT:
For more generalized solution refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server).

Comment: Excellent! But I wonder whether we can present it into simple.sql server query instead of T-Sql. Also I have to check if the number of characters in string are 9