# wants to remove special characters from particular colomn in sql table

Tags: sql

I have one table which name is emp in this table one colomn which name is empname, there are more then 2000 employees , in this coloumn some names are like ' Avinash K. Odedra' it should be like 'Avinash K Odedra' , Now i wants to remove this special characters from it, Pls. Suggest me SQL Query for same.

Comment: Please show what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly well formed question..

A quick google, with the words 'SQL Replace Special Characters', provided this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server).

Looks like it might do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
update emp
set empname = REPLACE(empname,"'","")
```

Answer (score 0):

pls search your doubts before posting a question

removes special characters

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
  SET @str = '(remove) ~special~ *characters. 3 5 from string 1 in sql!'
  WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
      SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')

  SELECT @str
```