String Building in VB for SQL to replace special characters with blank spaces
Given the fake number (800) 555-1212, we need to search the database.
However, there is no requirement on how someone specifies their phone number, so it could be any of the following:

8005551212
18005551212
800-555-1212
800 555 1212
800.555.1212

You get the idea.
In the VB code that builds the SQL, I can filter out the unwanted characters in the txtPhone.Text form input and build the SQL query to REMOVE the characters using a toRemove array:
Dim toRemove() As String = {"+", "-", "(", ")", ".", " ", ","}
Dim phone As String = txtPhone.Text.Trim()
Dim append As String = "Phone.Number"
For Each x As String In toRemove
    phone = phone.Replace(x, "")
    append = String.Format("REPLACE({0}}, '{1}', '')", append, x)
Next
If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone)) Then
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sSQL)) Then
        sSQL = String.Format(" {0}} LIKE '{1}'", append, phone)
    Else
        sSQL = String.Format("{0} AND {1} LIKE '{2}'", sSQL, append, phone)
    End If
End If

However, the code is failing where I populate the append variable - on the first pass through the "For Each" loop:
    append = String.Format("REPLACE({0}}, '{1}', '')", append, x)


stringbuilder Input string was not in a correct format.

How should I change this code to get it to work?

Similar, but the solution there will not work - https://stackoverflow.com/q/26739837/27599767

You have two times {0}} wihch I suspect need to be changed to {0}.

@PeterB - that was it. Thanks! Put it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

A typo is a "close" reason, so I will vote te close the question instead.

Instead of specifying the characters you don't want, you can remove any characters that are not the ones you do want. A good use for a regular expression: Dim ph = "1-800(234).987,654 pqr" Dim digits = Regex.Replace(ph, "[^0-9]", "") Console.WriteLine(digits) outputs "1800234987654". (It will need an Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions.)

The LIKE argument in the SQL is incomplete: you need LIKE '%{1}%' - ref: LIKE (Transact-SQL). And you really should be using SQL parameters, not concatenating values into query strings.

try this
Dim toRemove() As String = {"+", "-", " 
  (", ")", ".", " ", ","}
Dim phone As String = 
  txtPhone.Text.Trim()
Dim append As String = "Phone.Number"

For Each x As String In toRemove
      phone = phone.Replace(x, "")
      append = 
       String.Format("REPLACE({0}, 
       '{1}', '')", append, x)
    Next

  If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone)) 
 Then
  If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sSQL)) Then
    sSQL = String.Format(" {0} LIKE 
   '{1}'", append, phone)
Else
    sSQL = String.Format("{0} AND {1} 
 LIKE '{2}'", sSQL, append, phone)
   End If
 End If


Not the answer I needed, but I will award it to someone before Peter closes it.

@jp2code you should only accept an answer if it actually addresses your problem.  I can't say whether this answer does or doesn't do so, but it would be nice if there were some explanation to go along with the code.

@jp2code Re: "Not the answer I needed, but I will award it to someone before Peter closes it." Accepting answers that 1) don't answer the question and 2) don't provide any form of explanation, is doing a disservice to any future visitor. If your question deserves to be closed (and ultimately deleted) because it's caused by a typo, so be it.

The issue was in my formatting, as pointed out by Peter in the comments.
Dim toRemove() As String = {"+", "-", "(", ")", ".", " ", ","}
Dim phone As String = txtPhone.Text.Trim()
Dim append As String = "Phone.Number"
For Each x As String In toRemove
    phone = phone.Replace(x, "")
    append = String.Format("REPLACE({0}, '{1}', '')", append, x)
Next
If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone)) Then
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sSQL)) Then
        sSQL = String.Format(" {0} LIKE '%{1}%'", append, phone)
    Else
        sSQL = String.Format("{0} AND {1} LIKE '%{2}%'", sSQL, append, phone)
    End If
End If

