# Find and Replace All Special Character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to copy all row in new column with replacing all special character with -. my code is below.

**My table design**

[image]

```
 select * from mycode
    UPDATE mycode
    SET newName = Replace(myname, '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%', '-')
```

It's getting copy with my code but the special character are not replaced

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such thing like regex replace. Wish some day microsoft will add this feature...

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server

Comment: Well, there's no RegEx which comes pre-installed. However, you can install `CLR` RegEx functions. Guidelines can be found here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/ I usually find them extremely useful, at least replace.

Comment: @t-clausen.uk can you please link me the duplicate question here..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this query

```
DECLARE @specialchar varchar(15)
DECLARE @getspecialchar CURSOR
SET @getspecialchar = CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT poschar 
    FROM   MASTER..spt_values S 
           CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(newName ,NUMBER,1) AS poschar from mycode ) t 
    WHERE  NUMBER > 0 

           AND NOT (ASCII(t.poschar) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 
                     OR ASCII(t.poschar) BETWEEN 97 AND 122 
                     OR ASCII(t.poschar) BETWEEN 48 AND 57)

OPEN @getspecialchar 
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getspecialchar INTO @specialchar 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE mycode 
        SET newName =Replace(myname,@specialchar,'')
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getspecialchar INTO @specialchar 
END
CLOSE @getspecialchar 
DEALLOCATE @getspecialchar
```

Comment: Mukesh kalgude:   two vote give to your answer but I'm not getting the result

Answer (score 12):

Try to create this function

```
create function dbo.RemoveSpecialChars (@s varchar(256)) returns varchar(256)
   with schemabinding
begin
   if @s is null
      return null
   declare @s2 varchar(256)
   set @s2 = ''
   declare @l int
   set @l = len(@s)
   declare @p int
   set @p = 1
   while @p <= @l begin
      declare @c int
      set @c = ascii(substring(@s, @p, 1))
      if @c between 48 and 57 or @c between 65 and 90 or @c between 97 and 122
         set @s2 = @s2 + char(@c)
      set @p = @p + 1
      end
   if len(@s2) = 0
      return null
   return @s2
   end
```

and then do your `UPDATE`

```
   UPDATE mycode
    SET newName = dbo.RemoveSpecialChars(mycode)
```

Comment: Not getting the result can you make this without function

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly.  Does this also remove the TM and copyright characters as well?

Comment: Thank you its worked... i edit it before use to adjust so its suit my needs, because i still use space