# Special characters when exporting data (SQL) in ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssms

I having some dirty text when I using the function "Save Result As" in SSMS.

When a open the file in n++:

[image]

How SSMS show me:

[image]

I used some script to detect these Unicode characters, but the workaround for this take much time to complete (I have more than 300k records):
[Find and Replace All Special Character in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050086/find-and-replace-all-special-character-in-sql)

It's available some export configuration to ignore this special characters?

Tks,

Comment: Please try to open in the notepad?

Comment: Same result, a lot of dirty caracteres..