# Getting SQL View with no special characters, spaces and with

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The Base Table:

```
Someid   |         SomeName
_______________________________
    1    |    Name -,#
    2    |    Something else ,-'
```

Desired Output, preferably in a in view:

Alias for SomeName = SomeAlias

```
    SomeAlias
________________
     name
 somethingelse
```

So my question is how to create a view that removes all funky characters and spaces (Not numbers) and changes everything to lower case.

I do not want to alter the SomeName column or entries in any way.

I am using SQL Server 2014

**EDIT:**

For the sake of any pseudo Code:

Base table =

```
SomeTable
```

Output Table =

```
SomeView
```

Comment: How many types of non-alphanumeric characters do you expect. Is it limited to '-', '#', '-', and ''' or are there others?

Comment: You could certainly investigate the `replace()` and `lower()` functions. If, as HashPsi asked, your number of undesired characters is unmanageably high, a UDF might be a better solution.

Comment: There are quite a few resources online which help you with this. For starters take a look [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209164/query-to-search-an-alphanumeric-string-in-a-non-alphanumeric-column/31209294#31209294)

Comment: That and the `LOWER()` function.

Comment: @underscore_d replace will work fine if the number of characters to remove is limited. Otherwise, it will be better to write a function based on PATINDEX.

Comment: Well lets say an arbitrary amount of special characters. I am more than willing to specify them in the View Query.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function like below,

```
USE DBName; 
GO
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9]%'
Set @Temp = LOWER(@Temp)
While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

Return @Temp
End
```

You can use that function while creating a View,

```
USE DBName; 
GO
CREATE VIEW SomeView
AS
SELECT SomeID, [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters](SomeName) as SomeAlias
FROM SomeTable ; 
GO
-- Query the view
SELECT *
FROM SomeView;
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I will attempt this now!

Comment: Bear in mind these sorts of UDFs can be slowww. There are some mentions of possible ways to minimise slowdown in the other thread linked by HashPsi. However, I've never needed to do this, so I've not benchmarked whether this or any other method is fastest.

Answer (score 1):

there is some way to so it like REPLACE string , make FUNCTION to replace string and we can use regular expression also

```
DECLARE @regex INT,@string varchar(100)
SET @string='india!@#$%^&*()_+<>?:"{}| indian'
SET @regex = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', @string)
WHILE @regex > 0
BEGIN
SET @string = STUFF(@string, @regex, 1, ' ' )
SET @regex = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', @string)
END
SELECT @string
```