# Retrieving text data between special characters using sql

Tags: sql

Table A data

```
ID NAME
1 (abhe)
2 (gd
3 good
4 bfhd)
```

I want the result as below

```
ID NAME
1 abhe
2 gd
3 good
4 bfhd
```

How to solve this please? Guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: What RDBMS? Please also **explain** in English what you're trying to do - don't just dump a *before* and *after* on us and let us **guess** what it is you want to do ......

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server

Comment: What if there are a '(' or ')' somewhere inside the text, keep or remove? Or a ')' first, or a '(' last?

Comment: That can be done using this query select id,replace(replace(name,'(',''),')','') from table_name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSI SQL answer, to remove leading `(` and trailing `)`:

```
select id, TRIM(leading '(' from TRIM(trailing ')' from name))
from tablename
```