# Removing Special character from string sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

my table have column contain data like this.

**SQL 2008**

```
97W
125/ 122Q
121/ 118Q
121/ 118S
123/ 120S
112H
111H
```

i am trying to remove data before / so output will look like as

```
97W
122Q
118Q
118S
120S
112H
111H
```

can anyone share experience how can i achieve if came across such scenario.

Thanks,

Comment: check answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server

Comment: If the output is going to your presentation layer eventually, you could handle this from your app.  SQL Server isn't the greatest tool for regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(mycol, LEN(mycol) - CHARINDEX('/', mycol)))
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0c570/2)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one

```
Select LTRIM(SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('/', col) + 1, LEN(col)))
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression to check whether the string contains `/`, if yes use `CHARINDEX` to find the index of `/` and get the right part. Else the string as it is.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN your_column_name LIKE '%/%' 
    THEN LTRIM(RIGHT(your_column_name, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(your_column_name), 1) - 1)) 
    ELSE your_column_name END AS new_string
FROM your_table_name;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee495/1)