# Show/extract only the character(s) match in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

How can I extract and show only the characters from a string on a column I am searching in SQL Server if the position of the characters varies on the string

Example input:

```
Mich%ael#
#Scott
Ran%dy
A#nder%son
```

Output:

```
%#
#
%
#%
```

I only able to think of a query like

```
select
    columnname
from 
    dbo.tablename with (noLock)
where 
    columnname like '%[%#]%'
```

but this would not strip and show only the characters I want. I looked at `substring()` function but this requires knowing the position of the character to be stripped.

Comment: Replace letters with empty string.

Comment: Use REPLACE and PATINDEX with [^a-zA-Z]. There's tons of examples.

Comment: @PM77-1 Is it not the replace function requires that I indicate the exact input string? REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement ) Would it work if the string expression vary can I use regular expression on replace function?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server) may help you

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want or can't use a UDF, consider the following:

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeField varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Mich%ael#'),
('#Scott'),
('Ran%dy'),
('A#nder%son')

Select A.*
      ,Stripped = max(B.Value)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Value=Stuff((Select '' + String 
                 From  (
                         Select String= Substring(a.b, v.number+1, 1) From (select A.SomeField b) a
                         Join master..spt_values v on v.number < len(a.b)
                         Where v.type = 'P'
                        ) A
                 Where String in ('%','#')      --<<<< This is Your Key Filter
                 For XML Path ('')),1,0,'') 
             ) B
 Group By SomeField
```

Returns

```
SomeField   Stripped
#Scott      #
A#nder%son  #%
Mich%ael#   %#
Ran%dy      %
```

Comment: Do i need to have a temp table to insert the values for this to work? If my input values run into hundreds of thousands i think it would not be practical to explicitly declare them all.

Comment: @Dren Nope.  That was just for demonstration. Remove the first 6 lines  Change (at)YourTable to your actual table name, and SomeField to your field name

Comment: Thanks your solution is great. Just made a minor modifications to use regular expression on the where string (Where String like '%[-.%$#&\/:()]%')