# How to remove special characters from a string completely in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> *update myTable
>   set Column = REPLACE(Column,'₦', '')*
>   I tried to remove the **naira**  with the above command but it's not just working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

```
Update myTable set [Column] = REPLACE([Column],N'₦', '')  -- Assuming nvarchar()
```

You should try to avoid Reserved Words.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Dummy set myColumn = replace(myColumn,'abc','xyz');
```

where abc is character that you want to remove from mycolumn and xyz is substring that u want to replace with the special character