# Is there a way to use order by to order similar fields together?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to make similar values equivalent in an order by?

Say the data is:

```
name  | number
John. | 9
John  | 1
John. | 2
Smith | 4
John  | 3
```

I'd want to order by name and then number, so that the output looks like this, but `order by name, number` will put all `John` entries ahead of `John.` entries.

```
name  | number
John  | 1
John. | 2
John  | 3
John. | 9
Smith | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some more advanced treatment on the name field then.
This topic will help you strip non-alphabetic characters from your string before ordering:
[How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

But the fact that you need such a complex function makes me question the very building process of your Database: if "John" and "John." are the same person, they should have the same name. So if the "." is important, that means you need another field to store the information it represents.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Fuzzy String Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) and beyond that, [Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-matching.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex replace function to strip out all special characters in your data, replacing with a space. Then wrap that in a TRIM function to remove the spaces

```
  TRIM(CASE 
   WHEN name LIKE '%.%'
   OR name LIKE '%_%'
   OR name ~ '%\d%' --This is for a number
    THEN
      REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(\_|\.|\d)', ' ' ) END) AS name_processed
```

The bit in brackets means replace an underscore or (|) a period or a digit with whatever is after the comma, which here is a space

Now you can order by name_processed and number as well

```
 ORDER BY name_processed, number DESC
```

But you can always keep the original name in a SELECT afterwards if you wrote a subquery first through WITH. Let me know if you want to do this. Basically the syntx would be:

```
WITH processed_names AS (
SELECT
 name,
 TRIM(CASE 
   WHEN name LIKE '%.%'
   OR name LIKE '%_%'
   OR name ~ '%\d%' --This is for a number
   THEN
      REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(\_|\.|\d)', ' ' ) END) AS name_processed,
number
 FROM names
  ORDER BY 2,3 DESC)

SELECT
name,
number
 FROM processed_names;
```