# Using SQL escape characters in Powerbuilder inline SQL

Tags: sql, powerbuilder

I am trying to replace single quote characters in an inline SQL statement.

In SSMS:

```
SELECT REPLACE('test''test', '''', '')
Result: testtest
```

In Powerbuilder:

```
SELECT REPLACE(fieldname, '''', '')
INTO :ls_string
FROM tablename;
Result: 'Incorrect syntax near ''.
```

Basically, Powerbuilder complains about syntax because it doesn't know what to do with SQL's escape character. If I use Powerbuilder's escape character instead (`'~''` versus `''''` as the second argument for REPLACE), SQL Server complains about open quotes.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably will have to either put the statement in a datawindow object (using the SQL quote escape method) which you use in the application as a datawindow or datastore OR do the SQL in a function or stored proc.  If you go the function route you could call it in an imbedded SQL statement within Powerscript like your examples.

Something like

```
SELECT ufReplaceTwoQuotes INTO :ls FROM myTable USING SQLCA;
```

A third option would be to retrieve your data then do the replace within Powerscript (but then you have to wrestle with escaping the single quote within PowerBuilder).

Comment: This looks like the best way to go in my example. It's probably a good idea to have a DB function for stripping special characters anyway. I used [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server) as a reference point.