# Removing numeric/special character in a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, replace

I would like to remove all the numbers and special character within the string in t-sql. is there any way to do it?
Thanks!

## input

```
Provider_Name
LOBLAW PHARMACY 4075
THE DRUGSTORE PHCY
411 DRUGSTORE PHCY 
THE DRUGSTORE'S PHCY
LOBLAW DRUGSTORE1032
```

## output

```
Provder_Name
LOBLAW PHARMACY
THE DRUGSTORE PHCY
DRUGSTORE PHCY 
THE DRUGSTORES PHCY
LOBLAW DRUGSTORE
```

Comment: What version of Microsoft SQL are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

Comment: I am using microsoft sql @Sparky

Comment: What version number of Microsoft SQL (2012,2014,2016?)