# Count of special characters in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a list of passwords in all the possible combinations (Special characters, numbers, etc). I want to extract the list of all passwords that have more than 5 special characters.

Need some help on this query

```sql
Select Password from Login where Password like `%[a-zA-Z0-9]%` and Len(`%[a-zA-Z0-9]%`) >=5
```

Comment: What error occurs?

Comment: Are backticks really allowed as quotes?

Comment: What do you mean with "special characters"? It's not clear what you are asking and why your current query doesn't work.

Comment: The `password` column isn't encrypted?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Good point, though passwords should not be encrypted but [salted and hashed.](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Yes salted / hashed is correct (I don't use the right word). Many hashes using certain chars (like MD5 using A to Z and numbers so there can't be a chars like `-/+#!`).

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** Your questions suggests you are storing passwords as *plain text* in your database.
This is a ***major security risk***. Passwords should be stored as [**salted hash**](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), not encrypted and *never as plain text* (Thanks to Sebastian Brosch for noticing this).

Having said that, here's an answer to your question:

One way to do it is to break the string into single chars, and then simply query with `count`:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(30) = 'shS46@($8jr4';
With N10 AS
(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))V(N)
), Tally AS
(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@str)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As N
    FROM N10 ten
    CROSS JOIN N10 hundred 
    -- Passwords are usually 10-20 chars max length. 
    -- If you need more you can add another cross join to get 1000.
), Chars AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, N, 1) As C
    FROM Tally
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Chars
WHERE C NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z0-9]%'
```

Of course, if you already have a tally table you don't need to create a tally cte on the fly:

```
With Chars AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, N, 1) As C
    FROM Tally
    WHERE N <= LEN(@str)
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Chars
WHERE C NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z0-9]%'
```

And a complete version that uses a Login table with a Password column:
(and another way to populate an on-the-fly tally cte)

```
CREATE TABLE Login
(
    Password nvarchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO Login (Password) VALUES
('n9$%^Usj4jjr'),
('Nehj47$%^$'),
('MNAtokay543^A36#$^#%'),
('(*&^#$^dfh$%&'),
('$%^h345nfs54y');



With Tally AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 20 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As N
    FROM sys.objects

), Chars AS
(
    SELECT Password, SUBSTRING(Password, N, 1) As C
    FROM Login
    CROSS JOIN Tally 
    WHERE N <= LEN(Password)
)

SELECT Password
FROM Chars
GROUP BY Password
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN C NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z0-9]%' THEN 1 END) > 5
```

Results:

```
Password
(*&^#$^dfh$%&
MNAtokay543^A36#$^#%
```

Comment: OP wants a list of passwords with 5 or more special characters, maybe you should add that for completeness.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Agreed. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is *How to count of special characters in column?* and you don't provide the version you are working on then you can use **[`TRANSLATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**, **[`REPLICATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and **[`REPLACE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** functions as

```
CREATE TABLE [Login](
  [Password] VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO [Login] VALUES
('Password'),
('abc@def'),
('a@b@c_d_e/f'),
('Normal');

DECLARE @SC VARCHAR(3) = '@_/';

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, REPLACE(TRANSLATE([Password], @SC, REPLICATE(' ', LEN(@SC))), ' ', '') Result
  FROM [Login] 
)
SELECT SUM(LEN([Password]) - LEN(Result)) Cnt
FROM CTE;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----+
| Cnt |
+-----+
|   6 |
+-----+
```

Here is a **[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d1121fe107ef6d0b42880ca4c18e396)**

And also here is another way to do so

```
CREATE TABLE [Login](
  [Password] VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO [Login] VALUES
('Password'),
('abc@def'),
('a@b@c_d_e/f'),
('Normal Words');

WITH Chars AS
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING([Password], Number + 1, 1) Chr
  FROM [Login] CROSS JOIN master..spt_values
  WHERE [Type] = 'P'
)
SELECT COUNT(1) Cnt
FROM Chars
WHERE Chr NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z0-9]%' AND Chr <> '';
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9bf4cb078d343f24d7b6dcb297ef3cb)**

UPDATE:

> I want to extract the list of all passwords that have more than 5 special Characters.

```
CREATE TABLE [Login](
  [Password] VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO [Login] VALUES
('Password'),
('abc@def'),
('a@b@c_d_e/f$'),
('Normal Words'),
('My_$P@$$word_/');

DECLARE @SC VARCHAR(3) = '$@_/'; --It's just an example
SELECT *
FROM [Login]
WHERE LEN([Password]) - LEN(REPLACE(
                                   TRANSLATE([Password], 
                                             @SC, 
                                             REPLICATE(CHAR(9), LEN(@SC))
                                            ),
                                   CHAR(9), '')) >= 5;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06e8ffb52bb8ab143b9d76926cf47793)**

Comment: That would require you to store all "special characters in `@SC`. Not impossible but kind of tedious. It also requires version 2017 or higher since that's when `translate` was introduced.

Comment: Passwords can have a white space too.

Comment: OP doesn't provide the version and a sample data too

Comment: OP wants a list of passwords with 5 or more special characters, maybe you should add that for completeness.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Update it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, i understand that you are calling `nonalphanumberic` characters as special characters here. If so,you can acheive it in 2 ways.

1) If you know all the list of special character that may appear in your column and if you dont have privilege to create a `function`.

```
SELECT * from test 
WHERE (len(COL)- len(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col,
        '!',''),'@',''),'#',''),'$',''),'%',''),
        '^',''),'&',''),'*',''),' ','')) ) >=5;
```

2) If you can create a `function`.

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

And then `select`. Thanks to [G Mastros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server) for above function

```
Select * from test where (len(col) - len(dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters(col))) > =5;
```

[**DB FIDDLE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f99b5d2a0a489dbb1c53ede3ed4a1562)

Answer (score 0):

Using [NGrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) it's you can simply do this:

```
--Sample data
CREATE TABLE #Login(ID INT IDENTITY, PW nvarchar(20));
INSERT INTO #Login (PW) VALUES
('n9$%^Usj4jjr'),
('Nehj47$%^$'),
('MNAtokay543^A36#$^#%'),
('(*&^#$^dfh$%&'),
('$%^h345nfs54y');

SELECT      l.ID, SpecialChars = COUNT(*)
FROM        #Login AS l
CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(l.PW,1) AS ng
WHERE       PATINDEX('[^a-zA-Z0-9]',ng.token) = 1
GROUP BY    l.ID
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 5;
```

Returns:

```
ID          SpecialChars
----------- ------------
3           6
4           10
```