# Function to remove all Non-alpha-numeric characters, superscripts, and subscripts, except a dash '-'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a T-SQL function that only keeps a hyphen (dash '-') and removes all non-alphanumeric characters (plus all spaces, superscripts and subscripts) from a given string.

You can test Superscript/Subscripts in SSMS:

```
select  'Hello® World™ '
```

**Example:**

input string
[image]

output string:

> HelloWorld-ThisIsATest123

Any solutions or thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: I can understand the requirement to remove a set of characters such as "special" (although you still have to define what special is. Is "." special?). BUT, you cannot request ro remove *formatting* from a string. Because strings in sql do not contain formatting *in the first place*. You even had to use an image to show this here - you surely won't manage to fit a red subscript into a tsql string.

Comment: Hello George, I editted my question, changing special character to 'non-alphanumeric' characters.  However, the superscript/subscript can be seen and saved in SQLServer. Please see example above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link. This removes all alpha numeric characters.  You can include '-' also to the included list.

[How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

In this example for the answer from @George Mastros, use '%[^a-zA-Z0-9-]%'  for regular expression instead of '%[^a-z]%'

Here is the reformatted function to include '-' and numeric characters:

```
-- Reformatted function
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS

Begin
Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]%' 
While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

Return @Temp
End

--Call function    


 Select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters('Hello® World™   -123 !@#$%^')
```

OUTPUT: `HelloWorld-123`

Comment: David, thanks for editing and including the upper case A-Z,  but regex '%[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]%' was not removing the backslash for me from the string.  For some reason backslash is not required to escape '-'.  Did you try with a backslash in your input string?

Answer (score 0):

I identified my code's issue - I previously had exact same function which was NOT removing superscript / subscript, and I was wondering why. Here was the issue:  The input/output datatype should **NOT** be  `NVARCHAR` , but mere varchar,  else it will contain superscripts in the return string:

```
problem code :
    Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp NVarChar(1000))
           Returns NVarChar(1000)
           AS
            ...
```