# Remove Special characters from string column which has 500 million rows using SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

This is a question that's been answered before here: [How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

I have used it successfully for a previous project, but that was on a mere 100,000 rows. Although not super quick, it did the job.

I now need to work out how to scale this up to cope with hundreds of millions of rows, I have read about inline functions and am wondering if anyone else has managed to crack this.

As an example, It was previously taking 5 minutes to process 500,000 rows as part of a larger query. But now that the data set size has increased to 500,000,000 rows this is now taking almost 3 hours.

The code that was used before in a scalar function was this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: SQL Server isn't really made for that kind of operations. If possible, you should process this out of the SQL base and update the results.
Like going for a BCP out to get your column content and the primary key column and then process it in Java/Python/C# or whatever language you use and then BCP in to update your column based on the primary key and on the result of the external process.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am quite restricted with what I can do on the server, the data has to remain intact as the special characters are there on purpose and add meaning.

Comment: _data has to remain intact_ But you can cleanse it at the time of insertion or modification and store that result separately. In short - an RBAR approach will never scale (which is what a scalar function containing a loop is) nor does it make sense to do this at runtime with every query. Now is a good time to have a discussion with the entire team (or at least the leaders) about the most appropriate method to achieve your goal.

Comment: And just a note - any name should clearly indicate what it does or contains. Your function will keep alphabetic **and numeric characters**. And your linked answer also contains multiple solutions - did you try the others?

Comment: Sorry there is one crucial element that I have forgotten to add. The column that I am using joins to another table which filters the column to only keep a subset of the results. So the function is used in a join so that each row is cleaned before joined, if a match is found then it is returned.

Comment: @SQL_Novice the answer is, not with SQL. You could write a SQLCLR function that cleans the data using a regex, write a C# program that uses a regex to read and clean the data, do the same with SSIS, or in SQL Server 2016 and later, use an R or Python script. Just don't use SQL. A regex would take 1/100th of the CPU cycles this loop takes

Comment: @SQL_Novice of course, the *best* place to clean up is when inserting new data. It's always faster to clean eg 1000 new rows instead of 50M rows, most of which are already cleaned

Comment: This is how i am currently using the scalar function INNER JOIN CODE_LIST C ON C.CODE = dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters(CLEANED.CODE)