# Replace non-alpha characters only from the beginning of a string

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching

How to remove the non-alphabetic characters from the beginning of a string in SQL Server.

ex: `6Hai` should return `Hai` and `H6ai` should return `H6ai`

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: The version of SSMS is irrelevant as its just a client UI, you want `select @@version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pattern could be used to replace non-alphabetic characters from a string as below:

```
Declare @Temp as varchar(50)
set @Temp = '6Hai'
Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) = 1
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, 1, 1, '')

select @Temp
```

Or a function could be defined as :

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharactersFromStart](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) = 1
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, 1, 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

and invoke the function as :

```
Select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharactersFromStart('6Hai')
```

Refer this answer to remove all non-alpha characters : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008566/7804477

I have updated the function such that only the non-alphabetic characters from the beginning are removed:

`Stuff` and `PatIndex` are built-in functions.

This is the crucial condition to check only at the beginning of the string: `While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) = 1`

`Stuff(@Temp, 1, 1, '')` - this replaces the first character in the string with an empty character `''`. (the second argument is the starting position and the third argument denotes the number of characters to replace)