# How to transform Data in a query to get rid of special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically i have a mirror server that i can access in order to get info but i can't alter info in that database, basically i can do selects.
With this info i feed some temp tables that are used by partners that have their own ways of handling the data.
The issue is that recently I'm getting data, names and address names with special characters (í, ç,ã,etc..) that is causing some problems.

Is there a way to get rid of these types of characters (maybe replacing them) on my end , i.e. between my selects and the inserts on temporary tables?

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll be able to account for every special character using just `SELECT` statements. I usually have a `fun_NOSpecialCharacters(@inputString)` function in my databases that will strip out special characters and just replace with a space. But you would need access to create Scalar-valued Function. Do you have such access? There is a solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server) that uses recursive CTEs to strip out the special chars without a function.

Comment: Is it a finite and well defined set of characters that you already know you want to exclude?