# Get Rightmost Pair of Letters from String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Given a field with combinations of letters and numbers, is there a way to get the last (Rightmost) pair of letters (2 letters) in SQL?

```
SAMPLE DATA
RT34-92837DF82982
DRE3-9292928373DO
```

FOR THOSE, I would want
DF and
DO

For clarity, there will only be numbers after these letters.

Edits

This is for SQL Server.

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own string functions.)

Comment: Pair, does that mean exactly 2? What's expected to happen of there are AB4C at the end? Or 123DEF?

Answer (score 2):

I would remove any characters that aren't letters, using `REGEXP_REPLACE` or similar function based on your DBMS.

```
regexp_replace(col1, '[^a-zA-Z]+', '')
```

Then use a `RIGHT` or `SUBSTRING` function to select the "right-most".

```
right(regexp_replace(col1, '[^a-zA-Z]+', ''), 2)
substring(regexp_replace(col1, '[^a-zA-Z]+', ''),len(regexp_replace(col1, '[^a-zA-Z]+', ''))-2,len(regexp_replace(col1, '[^a-zA-Z]+', ''))
```

If you can have single occurrences of letters ('DF1234A124') then could change the regex pattern to remove those also - `([^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z])|[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Thank you so much, but it's not recognizing that function. Any idea what it would be for SQL Server?

Comment: @Padawan - as far as I can see T-SQL has no `regexp_replace` and doesn't really support regular expressions outside of `LIKE` conditions.

There are some alternatives such as [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Seems like you need to create a function or recursive query to validate each character yourself - this approach would however allow you to skip some of the steps and just start at the last character and work backwards until you found your pair of letters.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, *there will only be numbers after these letters*, you can use the Trim and Right functions as the following:

```
select 
  Right(Trim('0123456789' from val), 2) as res
from t
```

Note: This is valid from SQL Server 2017.

For older versions try the following:

```
select 
  Left
  (
    Right(val, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', Reverse(val))+1),
    2
  ) as res
from t
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KOYZ4bm8)