Why does a chain of replace in sql with an exponent 2 affect the digits 2?
I made a SQL function in my SQL Server DB that normalizes a string in order to make comparisons and joins.
But I have what seems to be a SQL inconsistency and I'd like to understand why.
The implementation of my function is :
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnCleanStringStrict (@str NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            LOWER(@str),
        '؜', ''), '‎', ''), '‏', ''), '‪', ''), '‫', ''), '‬', ''), '‭', ''),
        '‮', ''), '⁦', ''), '⁧', ''), '⁨', ''), '⁩', ''), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), '­', ''),
        '͏', ''), 'ᅟ', ' ') ,'ᅠ', ' '), '឴', ''), '឵', ''), '᠋', ''), '᠌', ''), '᠍', ''), '᠎', ''), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '),
        ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), '​', ''), '‌', ''), '‍', ''),
        ' ', ' '), ' ', ' '), '⁠', ''), '⁡', ''), '⁢', ''), '⁣', ''), '⁤', ''), '⁪', ''), '⁫', ''), '⁬', ''), '⁭', ''), '⁮', ''),
        '⁯', ''), '⠀', ' '), '　', ' '), 'ㅤ', ' '), '︀', ''), '︁', ''), '︂', ''), '︃', ''), '︄', ''), '︅', ''), '︆', ''), '︇', ''),
        '︈', ''), '︉', ''), '︊', ''), '︋', ''), '︌', ''), '︍', ''), '︎', ''), '️', ''), NCHAR(10), ' '), NCHAR(13), ' '), '', ''),
        'ﾠ', ' '), '￼', ''), '', ''), '', ''), NCHAR(9), ' '), '–', '-'), '‑', '-'), '¸', '.'), '·', '.'), '…', '...'),
        '’', ''''), '´', ''''), '‘', ''''), '’', ''''), '́', ''''), '`', ''''), '“', '"'), '”', ''), 'Á', 'a'), 'á', 'a'),
        'À', 'a'), 'à', 'a'), 'Â', 'a'), 'â', 'a'), 'Ä', 'a'), 'ä', 'a'), 'Ã', 'a'), 'ã', 'a'), 'Å', 'a'), 'å', 'a'), 'Æ', 'ae'),
        'æ', 'ae'), 'ß', 'b'), 'Č', 'c'), 'č', 'c'), 'Ç', 'c'), 'ç', 'c'), 'Ð', 'd'), 'ð', 'd'), 'É', 'e'), 'é', 'e'), 'È', 'e'),
        'è', 'e'), 'Ê', 'e'), 'ê', 'e'), 'Ë', 'e'), 'ë', 'e'), 'Í', 'i'), 'í', 'i'), 'Ì', 'i'), 'ì', 'i'), 'Î', 'i'), 'î', 'i'),
        'Ï', 'i'), 'ï', 'i'), 'Ñ', 'n'), 'ñ', 'n'), 'Ó', 'o'), 'ó', 'o'), 'Ò', 'o'), 'ò', 'o'), 'Ô', 'o'), 'ô', 'o'), 'Ö', 'o'),
        'ö', 'o'), 'Ō', 'o'), 'ō', 'o'), 'Õ', 'o'), 'õ', 'o'), 'Œ', 'oe'), 'œ', 'oe'), 'Ř', 'r'), 'ř', 'r'), 'Š', 's'), 'š', 's'),
        '™', 'tm'), 'Ú', 'u'), 'ú', 'u'), 'Ù', 'u'), 'ù', 'u'), 'Û', 'u'), 'û', 'u'), 'Ü', 'u'), 'ü', 'u'), '×', 'x'), 'Ý', 'y'),
        'ý', 'y'), 'Ÿ', 'y'), 'ÿ', 'y'), 'Ž', 'z'), 'ž', 'z'), '²', ' '), '', ' '), '-', ' '), '!', ' '), '"', ' '), '#', ' '),
        '$', ' '), '%', ' '), '&', ' '), '(', ' '), ')', ' '), '*', ' '), ',', ' '), '/', ' '), ':', ' '), ';', ' '), '?', ' '),
        '@', ' '), '[', ' '), '\', ' '), ']', ' '), '^', ' '), '_', ' '), '{', ' '), '|', ' '), '}', ' '), '~', ' '), '¨', ' '),
        '+', ' '), '<', ' '), '=', ' '), '>', ' '), '«', ' '), '»', ' '), '¢', ' '), '©', ' '), '®', ' '), '°', ' '), '•', ' '),
        '€', ' '), '¾', ' '), 'º', ' '), 'ø', ' '), 'þ', ' '), 'Þ', ' '), '''', ' '), '.', ' '), ' ', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', ' '))
END
GO

And when I make a query like :
SELECT dbo.fnCleanStringStrict('42, the answer is 42')
I get in return
'4 , the answer is 4 '
Instead of
'42, the answer is 42'.
I don't understand why my 2 are replace by ' '
I thought it might be one of the replace that removes the exponent 2 and indeed when I remove the replace with REPLACE( .......  ,'²', ' ') in my function I get '42, the answer is 42' as expected.
So it's obvious but I try just do REPLACE('42, the answer is 42'  ,'²', ' ') it return '42, the answer is 42', I also try to place LOWER in the replace and add random REPLACE in and outside but as expected it won't alter my string.
It doesn't seem to be due to an encoding issue either, the char 2 and ² doesn't have same code or be the upper / lower of each other.
It seems REPLACE( ... ,'²', ' ') can affect the digit 2 is certain circumstance, but I don't know when.
Someone know what append and why ?
Thanks in advance for your response.

You might have more luck with N'²' etc, don't mix varchar and nvarchars

If your database isn't in a UTF-8 collation, a lot of those characters aren't going to be what you think they are.

Also, apart from the last 3 REPLACEs, ™ and Æ (and probably a couple others I've missed), you could change all those nested REPLACEs into a single TRANSLATE, which would be far more readable.

Indeed on my installation, the result is 4 e answer is 4, presumably because of the “þ”. Whether and in what contexts SQL Server treats accented characters, cases etc. as identical depends on the collation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support Mine DB is set to Latin1_General_CI_AS

To strip everything not whitelisted by regex, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012802/2385435 Of course you may still want to transcribe umlauts and such according to your requirements beforehand, i.e. “ß” to “ss“ (Germans will frown at your “b”), “Þ” to “th”, “æ” to “ae” etc., although it’ll be quite the task depending on your ambition.

I would suggest that if you are really going to use this for joins and such you are starting down the path of a cripplingly slow application. Scalar functions are horribly slow, but using them in a join predicate or a where clause is going to be horrific.

The problem is you assumed that a literal varchar ('￼') for example, would not result in a loss of data; you were wrong. Because many of your characters are, in fact, not supported by ANSI, many of the characters you wanted to replace are replacing the wrong characters. You can fix that by using a literal nvarchar.
I must admit, however, that your query is really messy. This could be better served with a table with the replacements, and then some "fun" string building, but you have some outliers, like ™ to tm (and incorrectly have ß to B not ss). I try to tidy some of this up with TRANSLATE. For characters you want to remove, I TRANSLATE them all to a character you want to remove ($) and then REPLACE that with nothing. This results in a solution far easier on the eye, though still not easy to read:
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = N'42, thê Ànßwér îs 42'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
       REPLACE(TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(@str,N'`´·¸ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿČčŌōŘřŠšŸŽž́‑–‘’’“', N'''''..aaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooxuuuuyaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyyccoorrssyzz''--''''''"'),
                         N'­͏؜឴឵᠋᠌᠍᠎​‌‍‎‏”‪‫‬‭‮⁠⁡⁢⁣⁤⁦⁧⁨⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯︀︁︂︃︄︅︆︇︈︉︊︋︌︍︎️￼', N'$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'),'$',''),
       N'…',N'...'),
       N'Æ',N'ae'),
       N'æ',N'ae'),
       N'Œ',N'oe'),
       N'œ',N'oe'),
       N'™',N'tm'),
       N'ß',N'ss'),
       N' ', N'<>'), N'><', N''), N'<>', N' ');

db<>fiddle
Code appears malformed, but when copied appears correctly; seems a "bug" on Stack Overflow.

You’re not replacing some of the troublesome chars from the original question like ² or Þ? On my machine converting the original function to all N prefixes still kills the 2 and the “th”.

There might well be a couple I've missed, @BenderBoy, but then that code was a mess . It gives the OP most of what they need. One would hope the OP has the list in a more consumable format.
